# Android - getting from a Uri to an InputStream to a byte array?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get from an Android Uri to a byte array.

I have the following code, but it keeps telling me that the byte array is 61 bytes long, even though the file is quite large - so I think it may be turning the Uri **string** into a byte array, rather than the file :(

```
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fileUriString = " + fileUriString);
  Uri tempuri = Uri.parse(fileUriString);
  InputStream is = cR.openInputStream(tempuri);
  String str=is.toString();
  byte[] b3=str.getBytes();
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "len of data is " + imageByteArray.length
     + " bytes");
```

Please can someone help me work out what to do?

The output is "fileUriString = content://media/external/video/media/53" and "len of data is 61 bytes".

Thanks!

Comment: what's `cR`? You ask how to go "from a Uri to an InputStream" but you already got an `InputStream`, without saying how you got it.

Comment: @Vince the `cR` is an instance of ContentResolver class

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`is.toString()` will give you a String representation of the InputStream instance, not its content.

You need to read() bytes from the InputStream into your array. There's two read methods to do that, [read()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) which reads a single byte at a time, and [read(byte[] bytes)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29) which reads bytes from the InputStream into the byte array you pass to it.

---

Update: to read the bytes given that an InputStream does not have a length as such, you need to read the bytes until there is nothing left. I suggest creating a method for yourself something like this is a nice simple starting point (this is how I would do it in Java at least).

```
public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
  // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
  int bufferSize = 1024;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

  // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
  int len = 0;
  while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
  }

  // and then we can return your byte array.
  return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't solve the problem though, because I have to specify the length of the byte[] array before I supply it, and I can't get that from an InputStream. Any idea how I can work out the length of the data given the Uri?

Comment: You don't have to know the file size in advance. The proposed solution will work with any stream length.

Comment: why do we need to  declare a buffer size? could w eput any length and if so, is there no way to put entire contents at once?

Comment: @AP257 I'm not sure if it helps, but to read the number of bytes from input stream you can call `.available()` method

Answer (score 11):

With **Apache Commons**, you can read all the bytes from a `Stream` thanks to [`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) as next:

```
byte[] recordData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
```

download jar:
http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin way:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun readBytes(context: Context, uri: Uri): ByteArray? = 
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.buffered()?.use { it.readBytes() }
```

In Kotlin, they added convenient extension functions for `InputStream` like `buffered`, `use`, and `readBytes`.

- `buffered` decorates the input stream as `BufferedInputStream`
- `use` handles closing the stream
- `readBytes` does the main job of reading the stream and writing into a byte array

Error cases:

- `IOException` can occur during the process (like in Java)
- `openInputStream` can return `null`. If you call the method in Java you can easily oversee this. Think about how you want to handle this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
```

should be

```
while (inputStream.available() >0 && (len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
```

This way read will not block if stream has no available bytes as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611760/java-inputstream-read-blocking).

Comment: Blocking is the correct behaviour if you have only received half the file.  Checking availability is a dreadful alternative to checking for end of file.

Answer (score 1):

With Google Guava, you can use [`ByteStreams.toByteArray(InputStream)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray(java.io.InputStream)) to get all the bytes in the input stream:

```
InputStream is = ...;
byte[] bytes = ByteStream.toByteArray(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my idea :D

```
private static byte[] getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) 
{

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] bReturn = new byte[0];

    String line;
    try 
    {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "Big5"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String sContent = sb.toString();
        bReturn = sContent.getBytes();          
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (br != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                br.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
    return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: InputStreamReader is use Big5 encoding format, because my content have chinese character, you can use UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

if You have an Uri, instead of a regular file name, you should use Content Resolver.
[Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri)

I tried this, and it works.
Uri uri; // it is something, I've got from a file chooser. Of course, I must be sure, that the uri points to a filename, and it is not an image, or audio, or something else...

```
InputStream is=getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(is);
bu=new BufferedReader(ir);
String s;
while ((s=bu.readLine())!=null){
    //do something with the line...
}
bu.close();
```

I've omitted some try-catch-finally from the code, but the most important things are here.
The first thing is, that if you have an uri, you cannot use the standard file reader.