# FileInputStream to byte array in Android application

Tags: java, android

I have a FileInputStream created using `Context.openFileInput()`. I now want to convert the file into a byte array.

Unfortunately, I can't determine the size of the byte array required for `FileInputStream.read(byte[])`. The `available()` method doesn't work, and I can't create a File to check it's length using the specific pathname, probably because the path is inaccessible to non-root users.

I read about `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and it seems to dynamically adjust the byte array size to fit, but I can't get how to read from the `FileInputStream` to write to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - getting from a Uri to an InputStream to a byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436385/android-getting-from-a-uri-to-an-inputstream-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: The `byte[]` you supply to `read(byte[])` isn't intended to be the full size of whatever it is you're trying to read. It's a buffer that can hold the maximum number of bytes you're willing to read at a time, and each call to `read` will put some number of bytes into that buffer and return a number telling you how many bytes it put.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should work.

```
InputStream is = Context.openFileInput(someFileName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ((int bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
   bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved with another method though.

`while(is .available>0){
  bos.write(is.read())
}`

Comment: @Jeremy: Robby's method is the standard way of doing this in Java. His reads the input up to 1024 bytes at a time... yours reads it 1 byte at a time. I'd advise using his suggestion.

Comment: @Mihir May I ask, what do you mean by "this method will work only in rooted device."? Does that mean Robby's method isn't applicable in rooted devices (Android, embedded operating systems, etc.) or devices that are S_OFF or rooted (Specifcally devices mentioned in XDA forums)? Or do you mean that Jeremy's method is suitable for Android?

Comment: Should close the `ByteArrayOutputStream` like `bos.close();`

Comment: help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996878/showing-gif-image-with-library?noredirect=1#comment53820263_32996878

Comment: @MuhammadBabar as far as I can see the close() method has no effect.

Answer (score 9):

This is the easiest way

```
FileInputStream fis =  openFileInput(fileName);

byte[] buffer =   new byte[(int) fis.getChannel().size()];

fis.read(buffer);
```

Comment: Please note `openFileInput` method doesn't accept path separators. So instead of `openFileInput`, you can use `fis =  new FileInputStream (new File(filename_with_path));`

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-allocate the byte array using

```
int size = context.getFileStreamPath(filename).length();
```

This way, you will avoid allocating memory chunks every time your `ByteArrayOutputStream` fills up.

Answer (score 0):

For the method to work on any device and aplication you just need to replace:

```
InputStream is = Context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(yourFileURi);
```

This way you can encode external files as well.