# How to get particular number of bytes from a video file in android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that I want to get first 2^21 bytes of a video file which is resided in our sdcard. But I don't know to do the same? Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you adapt this code by limiting the number of bytes, it should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333908/fileinputstream-to-byte-array-in-android-application