# Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?

Tags: android, file, uri

In my app the user is to select an audio file which the app then handles. The problem is that in order for the app to do what I want it to do with the audio files, I need the URI to be in file format. When I use Android's native music player to browse for the audio file in the app, the URI is a content URI, which looks like this:

```
content://media/external/audio/media/710
```

However, using the popular file manager application Astro, I get the following:

```
file:///sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/GetupGetOut.mp3
```

The latter is much more accessible for me to work with, but of course I want the app to have functionality with the audio file the user chooses regardless of the program they use to browse their collection. So my question is, is there a way to convert the `content://` style URI into a `file://` URI? Otherwise, what would you recommend for me to solve this problem? Here is the code which calls up the chooser, for reference:

```
Intent ringIntent = new Intent();
ringIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
ringIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
ringIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ringIntent, "Select Ringtone"), SELECT_RINGTONE);
```

I do the following with the content URI:

```
m_ringerPath = m_ringtoneUri.getPath();
File file = new File(m_ringerPath);
```

Then do some FileInputStream stuff with said file.

Comment: What calls are you using that don't like content URIs?

Comment: There are a lot of content Uris where you cannot get the file path, because not all content Uris _have_ filepaths.  Don't use filepaths.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Just use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` to get an `InputStream` from a URI.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29)

Comment: Would this conflict with a user who uses Astro to get a file Uri?

Comment: Check the scheme of the URI returned to you from the chooser activity. If if uri.getScheme.equals("content"), open it with a content resolver. If the uri.Scheme.equals("file"), open it using normal file methods. Either way, you'll end up with an InputStream that you can process using common code.

Comment: Great thanks a ton! One more thing... I put the File path of the audio file the user chooses in a SharedPrefs field for the app so the user can preview the selected audio file at any time. When the scheme is file, this works fine. However with content this has some issues. Is there a way to successfully create a file with a content Uri?

Comment: Actually, I just re-read the docs for getContentResolver().openInputStream(), and it works automatically for schemes of "content" or "file", so you *don't* need to check the scheme... if you can safely assume that it's always going to be content:// or file:// then openInputStream() will always work.

Comment: Why do you need to create a file, exactly? You can open audio files via content URIs as well, using the Android MediaPlayer object.

Comment: Ah, good point. I suppose I could do a simple `uri.toString();` call on the content Uri, saved that in the SharedPrefs, then do a `Uri.parse(uriString);` to load the player... that should work right?

Comment: Is there a way to get the File instead of the InputStream (from content:...)?

Comment: Works for most things, except Google Drive. Any idea how to deal with Drive? (FileNotFoundException)

Comment: @kilaka You can get the file path but it's painful.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20559418/294855

Comment: This answer is insufficient for someone who is using a closed-source API that relies on Files rather than FileStreams, but yet wants to use the OS to allow the user to select the file. The answer @DanyalAytekin referenced was exactly what I needed (and in fact, I was able to trim a lot of the fat because I know exactly what kinds of files I'm working with).

Comment: @JasonLeBrun I am able to read from it using getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)  BUT  I need a way to write into that..kindly help

Comment: this gives me a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Updated link for androidx: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface

Comment: @DanyalAytekin how can i get file from google drive and upload it to my server, do u have any idea now??

Answer (score 52):

**This is an old answer with deprecated and hacky way of overcoming some specific content resolver pain points. Take it with some huge grains of salt and use the proper openInputStream API if at all possible.**

You can use the Content Resolver to get a `file://` path from the `content://` URI:

```
String filePath = null;
Uri _uri = data.getData();
Log.d("","URI = "+ _uri);                                       
if (_uri != null && "content".equals(_uri.getScheme())) {
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();   
    filePath = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();
} else {
    filePath = _uri.getPath();
}
Log.d("","Chosen path = "+ filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I couldn't use an InputStream like the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: How can i get other column values like `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` from Uri of type "file://" ?

Comment: Works great on samsung galaxy nexus with 4.3

Comment: This works only for local files, eg it does not work for Google Drive

Comment: how about getting same thing for audio

Comment: Sometimes works, sometimes returns file:///storage/emulated/0/... which doesn't exists.

Comment: Is the column "_data" (`android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA`) always guaranteed to exist if the scheme is `content://`?

Comment: This is a major anti-pattern. Some ContentProviders do provide that column, but you are not guaranteed to have read/write access to `File` when you try to bypass ContentResolver. Use ContentResolver methods to operate on `content://` uris, this is the official approach, encouraged by Google engineers.

Comment: this method needs an update, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA is deprecated as of now

Comment: `ImageColumns.DATA` is deprecated now. What to do.

Answer (score 28):

Try this....

get File from a content uri

```
fun fileFromContentUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): File {
    // Preparing Temp file name
    val fileExtension = getFileExtension(context, contentUri)
    val fileName = "temp_file" + if (fileExtension != null) ".$fileExtension" else ""

    // Creating Temp file
    val tempFile = File(context.cacheDir, fileName)
    tempFile.createNewFile()

    try {
        val oStream = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
        val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(contentUri)

        inputStream?.let {
            copy(inputStream, oStream)
        }

        oStream.flush()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return tempFile
}

private fun getFileExtension(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    val fileType: String? = context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(fileType)
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun copy(source: InputStream, target: OutputStream) {
    val buf = ByteArray(8192)
    var length: Int
    while (source.read(buf).also { length = it } > 0) {
        target.write(buf, 0, length)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer reallyyyyyyyyyyyy help me, thanks man, thaaaanks <3

Answer (score 14):

If you have a content Uri with `content://com.externalstorage...` you can use this method to get absolute path of a folder or file **on Android 19 or above**.

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        System.out.println("getPath() uri: " + uri.toString());
        System.out.println("getPath() uri authority: " + uri.getAuthority());
        System.out.println("getPath() uri path: " + uri.getPath());

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            System.out.println("getPath() docId: " + docId + ", split: " + split.length + ", type: " + type);

            // This is for checking Main Memory
            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                if (split.length > 1) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1] + "/";
                } else {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                }
                // This is for checking SD Card
            } else {
                return "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can check each part of Uri using `println`. Returned values for my SD card and device main memory are listed below. You can access and delete if file is on memory, but I wasn't able to **delete file from SD card** using this method, only read or opened image using this absolute path. If you find a solution to delete using this method, please share.

SD CARD

```
getPath() uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/612E-B7BF%3A/document/612E-B7BF%3A
getPath() uri authority: com.android.externalstorage.documents
getPath() uri path: /tree/612E-B7BF:/document/612E-B7BF:
getPath() docId: 612E-B7BF:, split: 1, type: 612E-B7BF
```

MAIN MEMORY

```
getPath() uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3A/document/primary%3A
getPath() uri authority: com.android.externalstorage.documents
getPath() uri path: /tree/primary:/document/primary:
getPath() docId: primary:, split: 1, type: primary
```

If you wish to get Uri with `file:///` after getting path use

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File(path));
documentFile.getUri() // will return a Uri with file Uri
```

Comment: i don't think that's the right way to do it in an application. sadly i'm using it in a quicky project

Comment: @Bondax Yes, you should work with  Content Uris instead file paths or File Uris. That's way storage access framework is introduced. But, if you wish to get file uri this is the most correct way of other answers since you use DocumentsContract class. If you check out Google samples  in Github, you will see that they also use to this class to get sub folders of a folder.

Comment: And DocumentFile class also new addition in api 19 and how you use uris from SAF. The correct way is to use a standard path for you app and ask user to give permission for a folder through SAF ui, save Uri string to shared preferences, and when it's needed access to folder with DocumentFile objects

Answer (score 14):

Inspired answers are [Jason LaBrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657557/5031257) & [Darth Raven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29142781/5031257). Trying already answered approaches led me to below solution which may mostly cover cursor null cases & conversion from **content://**  to **file://**

To convert file, read&write the file from gained uri

```
public static Uri getFilePathFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    String fileName = getFileName(uri);
    File file = new File(myContext.getExternalCacheDir(), fileName);
    file.createNewFile();
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
         InputStream inputStream = myContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
        FileUtil.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream); //Simply reads input to output stream
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

To get filename use, it will cover cursor null case

```
public static String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    String fileName = getFileNameFromCursor(uri);
    if (fileName == null) {
        String fileExtension = getFileExtension(uri);
        fileName = "temp_file" + (fileExtension != null ? "." + fileExtension : "");
    } else if (!fileName.contains(".")) {
        String fileExtension = getFileExtension(uri);
        fileName = fileName + "." + fileExtension;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

There is good option to converting from mime type to file extention

```
 public static String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    String fileType = myContext.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(fileType);
}
```

Cursor to obtain name of file

```
public static String getFileNameFromCursor(Uri uri) {
    Cursor fileCursor = myContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    String fileName = null;
    if (fileCursor != null && fileCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int cIndex = fileCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (cIndex != -1) {
            fileName = fileCursor.getString(cIndex);
        }
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, been looking at this for a week.  Don't like having to copy a file for this but it does work.

Answer (score 9):

Trying to handle the URI with content:// scheme by calling `ContentResolver.query()`is not a good solution. On HTC Desire running 4.2.2 you could get NULL as a query result.

Why not to use ContentResolver instead?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141800/3205334

Comment: But sometimes we only need the path. We don't really have to load the file into memory.

Comment: "The path" is useless if you don't have access rights for it. For example, if an application gives you a `content://` uri, corresponding to file in it's private internal directory, you will not be able to use that uri with `File` APIs in new Android versions. ContentResolver is designed to overcome this kind of security limitations. If you got the uri from ContentResolver, you can expect it to just work.

Answer (score 4):

Well I am bit late to answer,but my code is tested

check scheme from uri:

```
 byte[] videoBytes;

if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")){
        InputStream iStream =   context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            videoBytes = getBytes(iStream);
        }else{
            File file = new File(uri.getPath());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);     
            videoBytes = getBytes(fileInputStream);
        }
```

In the above answer I converted the video uri to bytes array , but that's not related to question, 
I just copied my full code to show the usage of `FileInputStream` and `InputStream` as both are working same in my code.

I used the variable context which is getActivity() in my Fragment and in Activity it simply be ActivityName.this

`context=getActivity();` //in Fragment

`context=ActivityName.this;`// in activity

Comment: I know it is not related to the question, but how would you then use the `byte[] videoBytes;`? Most answers only show how to use `InputStream` with an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following android package which can be easier a bit for you

https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode

Using the above package the code can be like

**To Import use below Line**

> import com.blankj.utilcode.util.UriUtils;

Your code can be like

```
File f = UriUtils.uri2File(result);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're **absolutely sure** that your `content:` Uri points to a real file, you can do the following trick:

```kotlin
context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r").use { fileDescriptor ->
    if (fileDescriptor == null) {
        throw NullPointerException("ParcelFileDescriptor from $uri was null")
    }
    val path = "/proc/${android.os.Process.myPid()}/fd/${fileDescriptor.fd}"
    val fileUri = Uri.fromFile(File(path).canonicalFile)
}
```

Here we open the file using `ContentResolver`, construct a path to an underlying Linux file descriptor and resolve a real file path by getting `canonicalFile`.

Comment: Does not work with samsung, it seems that they have restricted these calls
 ```java.lang.SecurityException: MediaProvider: User 11518 does not have read permission on file:///proc/8285/fd/25```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getNativePath(String javaString) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(javaString);
    ContentResolver resolver = this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = null;
    try {
        pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return "pipe:" + pfd.detachFd();
};
```

you can get the fd and return a fd string to native code

Answer (score -2):

you can get filename by uri with simple way

[Retrieving file information](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info)

```
fun get_filename_by_uri(uri : Uri) : String{
    contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
        cursor?.let {
            val nameIndex = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            it.moveToFirst()
            return it.getString(nameIndex)
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

and easy to read it by using

```
contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
```