# Get Uri from real Path

Tags: android

I have a real path of a file like "file:///mnt/sdcard/3dphoto/temp19.jps"
, how can i get the uri like "content://media/external/images/media/1 "?

Comment: Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri Could you provide the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transform your "file://..." in a file path, find the id of the item with the following code, and then append it to provider URI. In addition, based on file extensions, use the right provider (for example MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI or MediaStore.Image.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

```
/**
 * Given a media filename, returns it's id in the media content provider
 *
 * @param providerUri
 * @param appContext
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 */
public long getMediaItemIdFromProvider(Uri providerUri, Context appContext, String fileName) {
    //find id of the media provider item based on filename
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns._ID, MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = appContext.getContentResolver().query(
            providerUri, projection,
            MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] { fileName },
            null);
    if (null == cursor) {
        Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Null cursor for file " + fileName);
        return ITEMID_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    long id = ITEMID_NOT_FOUND;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return id;
}
```

Sometimes MediaProvider doesn't refresh immediatly after one media file is added to device's storage. You can force to refresh its records using this method:

```
/**
 * Force a refresh of media content provider for specific item
 * 
 * @param fileName
 */
private void refreshMediaProvider(Context appContext, String fileName) {
    MediaScannerConnection scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new MediaScannerConnection(appContext, null);
        scanner.connect();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (scanner.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Requesting scan for file " + fileName);
            scanner.scanFile(fileName, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG_LOG, "Cannot to scan file", e);
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what should I pass to the Context?

Comment: the context of the application, the calling activity, any kind of Context you can get from calling code...

Comment: Any one knows how the reverse is possible? Actually I want to create a file out of "content://"

Answer (score 6):

I had same question for my file explorer activity...but u should knw tht the contenturi for file only supports the mediastore data like image,audio and video....I am giving you for getting image content uri from selecting an image from sdcard....try this code...may be it will work for you...

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
        String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            Uri baseUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media");
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "" + id);
        } else {
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what if it is not an image or video? What should we do then?

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way:

```
File file = new File(Path);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: This one can not solve in case :special character of folder. Not good.