# Load a file from external storage to Inputstream

Tags: android, inputstream, android-file

i have a video file in my external directory. how can i load it to inputstream variable.
For the time being i am reading file in the res/raw folder but i want to read it from the sdcard. also i dont know about the name of the file but its path will be recieved through intent.
check the following code

```
public class SonicTest extends Activity
{
VideoView videoView;
String uri;
InputStream soundFile;
File file;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                      
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

public void play(View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            float speed= (float) 1.0;
            float pitch= (float) 1.5;
            float rate= (float) 1.0;
            uri= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            uri=uri+"/video.3gp";
            AndroidAudioDevice device = new AndroidAudioDevice(22050, 1);
            Sonic sonic = new Sonic(22050, 1);
            byte samples[] = new byte[4096];
            byte modifiedSamples[] = new byte[2048];
            InputStream soundFile = null;

    //soundFile = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri));
    soundFile=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.video3);
    Log.i("testing","check if SoundFile is correct "+soundFile);

            int bytesRead;

            if(soundFile != null) {
                sonic.setSpeed(speed);
                sonic.setPitch(pitch);
                sonic.setRate(rate);
                do {
                    try {
                        bytesRead = soundFile.read(samples, 0, samples.length);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(bytesRead > 0) {
                        sonic.putBytes(samples, bytesRead);
                    } else {
                        sonic.flush();
                    }
                    int available = sonic.availableBytes(); 
                    if(available > 0) {
                        if(modifiedSamples.length < available) {
                            modifiedSamples = new byte[available*2];
                        }
                        sonic.receiveBytes(modifiedSamples, available);
                        device.writeSamples(modifiedSamples, available);
                    }
                } while(bytesRead > 0);
                device.flush();
            }
        }
    } ).start();
}}
```

Comment: All three answers fail to understand what a URI is and that they aren't always a file path. If you had the file path you'd have figured it out yourself, but the posted answers just don't answer the actual question.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try

```
File file = new File(Uri.toString());
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Then you can read from the stream.

Comment: well thanks its working. but i cant here anything there is too much noise. Any idea why is it like this?

Comment: Note: this answer only works for OP's question (OP have a uri that is a file path). In more general case, Uri.toString() does not necessarily returns a file path (uri could instead be a content path, or url, etc.). This method only works for Uri that is a file path. check answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri

Comment: Well the question is entitled "Load a file from external storage".  I think assuming the incoming uri is a file is safe in that case.

Answer (score 11):

```
String fileName = "OfflineMap/maps.xml";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName;
File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working code, you can InputStream with a storage file:

```
       File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       File file = new File(sdcard,"Demo.xml");
       InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
soundFile = openFileInput(uri);
```