# Can a DocumentsProvider <provider> tag be used in an Android manifest targeting APIs < 19?

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, android-4.4-kitkat

So I'm trying to implement the new Storage Access Framework stuff introduced in Android 4.4 (KitKat).  I've extended a [DocumentsProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html) class as [described on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxHVeXbK1P4), which works [great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content/20209829#20209829) when I try it on KitKat (API 19) devices.  I have a content provider, and my app acts as a client-- it's a great file picker to replace the one I had to custom-write.

But when the code is run on older devices, such as API 8 (Froyo), it dies on launch with an error that looks like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  702): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.example.MyProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example-2.apk]
```

Makes perfect sense-- The `DocumentsProvider` class was introduced in KitKat, so of course it doesn't run in Froyo (API 8).

To try to deal with older devices and make it fallback to the file picker I wrote previously, I wrapped all the code referencing `MyProvider` (my `DocumentsProvider`) with a `if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)` conditional... so you'd think I'd be safe...

Trouble is, `DocumentsProvider` requires the provider be registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` within a `<provider>` element.  I see no way of saying "Ignore this and don't try to load `MyProvider` on older APIs."  And I don't see any way of declaring `<provider>` programmatically either.  Or any kind of legacy solution.  It seems to be an all-or-nothing thing hard-coded into the Manifest.

If I remove the `<provider>` stuff from the manifest, the app runs perfectly in Froyo without errors (it's not trying to load or use `DocumentsProvider` at all).  But I do need it there for KitKat to work with the new Storage Access stuff.

Anyone have any thoughts?  Is it possible to use `DocumentProvider` in a way that it works on API >= 19 but is completely ignored on older devices?  Some kind of tricky wrapper-class... or a stub `ContentProvider` class... or *something*?  Whatever class I can get Froyo to think is there, it'll never get called/used, at least by my app.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a boolean in your resources. Set it to `true` for api level 19, `false` for everything else.

So in **res/values/bool.xml**:

```
<item name="provider_enabled" type="bool">false</item>
```

In **res/values-v19/bool.xml**:

```
<item name="provider_enabled" type="bool">true</item>
```

Now in the Manifest, add the following to your provider:

```
android:enabled="@bool/provider_enabled"
```

Comment: Holy cow.  So easy.  Last night I was trying to figure how to get a /values-v19 to apply to the manifest and had no idea you could do this-- it worked great.  (I used the `<bool>` item for simplicity)  Thanks.  As soon as I get enough reputation points I'll be back to up-arrow this.

Comment: UPDATE:  Oh wow-- a similar technique is actually suggested in the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html docs using a boolean called "atMostJellyBeanMR2" so anyone following those instructions might want to reuse it.

Comment: --never mind, don't re-use it.  It's false when you want it to be true, and vice-versa.  Just set up another bool :)