# Kitkat, error while trying to load an image

Tags: android

I'm trying to load an image.. wel this works well when i using API 18 or lower, but if i use API 19 (Kitkat) a problem of security ocurrs... i'm not sure how to solve this, but the cursorloader throught me an exception. I read somenting like

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client

but without a good result. If you saw below i've a new path about the image file, so i can manage this?

*STACK_TRACE=java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1384 from pid=3632, uid=10027 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()*

```
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                uri, 
                projection,
                null, null, null);
```

Some permissions that i've in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Comment: Have you declared the permission in your manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>`

Comment: Yes i add it and dosen't work.. i edit the question and add some permissions that i'm using. I think maybe needs a provider but i'm sure.

Comment: Facing the same problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well exist a simple solution for this:

```
    public static final String KITKAT_VALUE = 1002;

Intent intent;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
                                intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                            } else {
                                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                        }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == KITKAT_VALUE ) {
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
     // do something here
     }
  }
}
```

NOTE: No is necessary and additional permission to do this (Manifest modifications). Only write this few code and then you will be able to select images from "Downloads" or from "Recent"

i read this post, help me to write this.

[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

also check this too

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#client

Thanks finder.

**NOTE: This is a temporal solution, i couldn't find a better way to make it works. But for now i can say, problem solved.**

Comment: It's worth to mention that `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` opens new files chooser which unfortunately does not support many file providers like `Dropbox`. So user literally can't choose file in his `Dropbox`. At least now.

Answer (score 5):

I just found this error today.

It is a reported bug for cordova and KitKat. You can find detailed info here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5398

The bug occurs when the pictured selected comes from the new KitKat options "Recent", "Downloads", etc.

If you go all the way down to the Gallery app and open the standard gallery, you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I found this while i was trying a lot of times. Well now we know that the problem never happens if i select gallery.. but the user that will use the app don't know that. For now i don't have a solution for this, if you found it tell me please.

Comment: still...am stuck here

Comment: stuck in the same. dont know what to do :(

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on where your uri comes from.
If the Uri was returned from the file picker, all should work without exceptions.

If you build the Uri by yourself or have persisted the Uri, then there can be problems.

This is inherent in the new Storage Access Framework introduced with Android 4.4 KitKat.

If the user selects files for opening in the file picker, the system grants permission for exactly theese files to your app. Theese permissions are valid as long as the device is not rebootet.

If the Uri is persisted, then the rights granted to access the Uri must also be persisted. For more details look here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#permissions