# copy a picture from android photo-library causes error

Tags: android, cordova

get this error when I try to resolve the local filesystem uri by phonegap:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider
```

I use the camera to access the photo-library and receive this file_uri:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A355
```

Then I try to access the local filesystem:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file_uri, function(a){console.log("success");}, function(b){console.log("fail");});
```

That's where I receive this error:

```
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ java.lang.SecurityException:         Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri          content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:355 from pid=22659, uid=10098    requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1796)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(FileUtils.java:263)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.execute(FileUtils.java:150)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:65)
02-18 10:13:14.546  app W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:229)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:214)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at     com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-18 10:13:14.556  app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Btw.: I tried this scenario on iOS and it works without a problem.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="openApi" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: can you give the list of your manifest.xml permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple fix to this problem:

replace this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A352
```

by this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%253A352
```

if you are using JavaScript you can use this code:

```
var path = content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A352;
path = path.replace("%", "%25");
```

this technique force the uri to let pass "%3A" as it is, without changing it to ":",

Answer (score 2):

Whenever some `uri` is passed into `<img src="uri" />` it's implicitly decoded from

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A9888 **(1)**

into

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:9888 **(2)**

However, after returning from `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` Android provides you with the read permission for  **(1)**, not **(2)**. In this case `WebView` will expectantly log an error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri
>   content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:9888
>   from pid=13163, uid=10165 requires
>   android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

or

> Unable to open content URL

**Code snippet**

All you need to resolve the issue is

```
    String uriToUseInWebView = transformForWebView(uri.toString());

    private String transformForWebView(String uri) {
        for (int i = 0; i < timesDecodingWebView(); i++)
            uri = uri.replace("%", Uri.encode("%"));
        return uri;
    }

    private int timesDecodingWebView() {
        if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals("4.4.2")) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

in your Java code before passing `uri` into HTML/JS to ensure that **(1)** will be actually loaded.

I've tested that on 4.4.2, 4.4.4 and 5.0. The funny part is that Android 4.4.2 decodes the `uri` internally twice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the correct permission to manifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: It seems a missing permission. Let's try: add all permissions and clear one at time...

Comment: I added all permissions (taken from this post: XML Android Permissions List Full). But it's still not working.

Comment: Is it possible that the url is not ok?

Comment: let's try to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248178/kitkat-error-while-trying-to-load-an-image

Comment: I have a virtual device with android 4.3 running (noKitKat). And it works .. so, I guess I have to change the uri .. don't I?

Comment: Okies ... check that in a few minutes :)

Comment: I guess that I have to wait for cordova 3.5. But it's ok, as long as it works in the common picture library section.