# Android kitkat: fileChooser + fileTransfer cordova plugin not working

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-intent

I am building an android application using apache cordova framework.

In android 4.4  won't work as described in following issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5294

For that I am using below filechooser plugin

https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser

Till now I am able to open file chooser dialog and select the file.

When I try to upload the file using following code

```
                var def = Q.defer();
                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey = "file";
                options.fileName = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var params = {};
                params.title = title;
                options.params = params;
                options.trustAllHosts = true;
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                var url = Constants.API_SERVICE_URL + "upload";
                ft.upload(file, encodeURI(url), function(res) {
                    // check for HTTP OK status and success
                    if(res.responseCode === 200 && res.response && res.response.status !== "fail") {
                        def.resolve(res.response);
                    } else {
                        def.reject(res);
                    }
                    def.resolve(res);
                }, function(err) {
                    def.reject(err);
                }, options);
                return def.promise;
```

The file here would be something like

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:28029
```

I got java.lang.SecurityException

I did so much research on the topic, but I am not able to find answers.

This issue is described here
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5398

The issue there is marked as resolved, but the workaround described in this comment is not working

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5398?focusedCommentId=13977552&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13977552
```

If I do that I am getting file not found exception, the file url is like

```
file://storage/emulated/0/images/image.png
```

The below stackoverflow question is related

[Kitkat, error while trying to load an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248178/kitkat-error-while-trying-to-load-an-image)

The question has an answer, I tried that also but that is also not working.

I added MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission in my android manifest file
List of all permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But if I choose the file from gallery option or old file manager. It is working fine.

Any idea of how I can resolve this ?

**EDIT:**

Apache cordova version 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Cesidio DiBenedetto plugin instead of the one you used
https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser

Here you have a sample project using it

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FileBrowserAndroidTest

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Could you please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701051/file-picker-in-cordova

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question at the right time! I was struggling for days and I have worked out it.

The code below works well for Android version below 4.4 but not for kitkat.

```
options.fileName = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

I have created an Android project and I found that when it comes to Android 4.4, the 'file'(file name) seems to be '7961'(or other number) instead of the actual name 'abc.png'.
What we need is the code below.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, function (fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                            var fileName = fileEntry.name;
                            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                            options.headers = {Connection: "close"};
                            options.fileKey = "uploadfiles";
                            //change the code below.
                            // if(fileName.indexOf('/')>-1){
                            // options.fileName = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                            options.fileName = fileEntry.nativeURL.substr(fileEntry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Let me know if that is working for you.

Comment: @Syed I think you could create an Android project to debug what the actual uploading url is. That may help.