# Security Exception when open image via Intent.ACTION_VIEW. Lollipop

Tags: android

In my app I have a list with images chosen from standart android (lollipop) filepicker. Each image have URI like content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A105628.

Code for image selection:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 intent.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

By clicking on image in list intent with ACTION_VIEW invoked. And view app crashes with exception.

Code for image view:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewIntent.setDataAndType(finalPhoto, "image/*");
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{247dd26c 18416:com.google.android.apps.plus/u0a51} (pid=18416, uid=10051) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4589)
            at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2439)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1442)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1064)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:921)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:646)
            at jcq.a(PG:129)
            at dcv.f(PG:28)
            at dcv.j(PG:16)
            at hxz.d(PG:40)
            at df.e(PG:242)
            at dg.a(PG:51)
            at dg.c(PG:40)
            at dx.call(PG:123)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I read about SAF, is it possible to delegate granted permission from my app to another app (viewer)?

PS: I saw this workaround. [Android KitKat securityException when trying to read from MediaStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837358/android-kitkat-securityexception-when-trying-to-read-from-mediastore/20186938?s=ebf6545517de487bb12b27402789162c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is add this flag `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`
to ACTION_VIEW intent

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

After that it should work

---

#### Edit

Perhaps you can take a look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20382826/2767703

P.S. Didn't the Android KitKat securityException answer help you?

Comment: I already have this permission. And I know what does it mean "requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS " ;)

Comment: @Kolchuga I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

**You should add this to your Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Use this code for openGallery**

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
```