# Select image from Camera or Gallery and Store in SDcard in KitKat

Tags: android, camera

Hi i am new android developer and i am working on an android app in which i want to show a dialog to user to select image from camera or gallery and after user selects image i want to store it in SD Card.i have already done it for OS versions less than 4.4 but i want to do this for 4.4 and above versions.i have already visited link
[Android kitkat Image Selection From Gallery Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144042/android-kitkat-image-selection-from-gallery-issue)
Please give some code examples as well as guidance.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

create the final list of possible Intents with one new Intent for each retrieved activity like this:

```
List<Intent> yourIntentsList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(camIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
    final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(camIntent);
    finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
    yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
}

List<ResolveInfo> listGall = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(gallIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listGall) {
    final Intent finalIntent = new Intent(gallIntent);
    finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
    yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
}
```

Comment: but i want to take image and store it in sdcard as well