# NullPointerException at add picture to gallery

Tags: android, gallery

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
>   at java.io.File.(File.java:134) 
>                                                                                   **at  ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton.DeliverActivity.galleryAddPic(DeliverActivity.java:308)
>   at
>   ua.romanpotapskiy.antihawk.prokaton.DeliverActivity.onClick(DeliverActivity.java:246)**
>                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Prokaton/Big");
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        imageName = image.getName();
        ...
        return image;
    }

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Error on this line:
File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

Error on Android 4.0.3. In the other version works fine.

Comment: there is some problem with slashes in your file path

Comment: The error clearly indicates that `mCurrentPhotoPath` is null so you need to assign a non-null value to it prior to your call to `galleryAddPic()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, my guess is that you experienced the error prior to `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` getting called since it is this method that calls the `createImageFile()` method which sets the `mCurrentPhotoPath` variable with a non-null value.

A simple fix would be to update the `galleryAddPic()` method with a not null check like so:

```
    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        if (mCurrentPhotoPath == null) {
            return;
        }
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

Comment: as i said, this code works perfect on antother android versions. I add ur "if" and now code catch exception.

Answer (score 0):

mCurrentPhotoPath is null in your code so provide full code to check this error.[image]

image.getabsolutePath(); is null in your code.

Comment: Ok, thx, but why image.getabsolutePath() null? As i said, this code works perfect on antother android versions. But on 4.0.3 i geting error.

Comment: in 4.0.3 process is changed to get path so thats why it getting null .if u agree this answer then supoort this answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260416/retrieve-absolute-path-when-select-image-from-gallery-kitkat-android    see this answer to get path

Comment: uh, cant undertand how to use it in my project :(

Comment: http://hmkcode.com/android-display-selected-image-and-its-real-path/ see this example it will help you to understand all code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100476/discussion-between-er-rakesh-prajapat-and-user3712384).

Comment: I answered you in the chat