# Selected path from image showing null

Tags: android

I have referred this [sample](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/).

Upload multiple files to server at  a time while click the upload button.

But i am getting selectedpath1 and selectedpath2 null pointer exception.I dont know how to solve this one.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

**Logcat:**

```
02-12 02:12:15.001: E/selectedImageUri(11964): content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A388
02-12 02:12:15.006: E/selectedPath1(11964): null
02-12 02:12:26.949: E/selectedImageUri(11964): content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A388
02-12 02:12:26.956: E/selectedPath2(11964): null
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_FILE1 = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE2 = 2;
    String selectedPath1;
    String selectedPath2;
    TextView tv, res;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    HttpEntity resEntity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
        tv.setText(tv.getText() + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE2);
            }
        });

        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(selectedPath1.equals(""))
                        && !(selectedPath2.equals(""))) {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                            "", "Uploading files to server.....", false);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            doFileUpload();
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select two files to upload.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openGallery(int req_code) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload "),
                req_code);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            Log.e("selectedImageUri", ""+selectedImageUri);

            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1) {
                selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);  -->path is Null

                Log.e("selectedPath1", ""+selectedPath1);

            }

            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE2) {
                selectedPath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                Log.e("selectedPath2", ""+selectedPath2);
            }
            tv.setText("Selected File paths : " + selectedPath1 + ","
                    + selectedPath2);
        }  
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload() {

        File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
        File file2 = new File(selectedPath2);
        String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2/upload_test/upload_media_test.php";
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
            FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
            FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile2", bin2);
            reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
            post.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            resEntity = response.getEntity();
            final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            if (resEntity != null) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE", response_str);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            res.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            res.setText("n Response from server : n "
                                    + response_str);
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Multiple File Upload from CoderzHeaven" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get First File" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Second File" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Upload" >
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Selected File path : " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/res"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Content URI returned can be different depending upon where the selection has been made from. Especially since Kitkat (API level 19) which introduces the Storage Access Framework (SAF) you get to see all your document storage providers while selecting a photo.
This issue (and fixes for it) has been addressed in the following StackOverflow threads:

[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

[retrieve absolute path when select image from gallery kitkat android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260416/retrieve-absolute-path-when-select-image-from-gallery-kitkat-android)

Or simply You can do following :-

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
        //Now you can do whatever you want with your inpustream, save it as file, upload to a server
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved now? If this solved your problem you can accept this.