# Get filepath and filename of selected gallery image in Android

Tags: java, android, filepath, android-gallery

I am creating an app which uploads a selected image from the gallery and uploads it to a web service.  The webservice requires the filename of selected image plus a base64 encoding of the file contents.  I have managed to achieve this with a hardcoded file path.  However, I am struggling to get the real filepath of the image.  I have read around the web and have this code, but it does not work for me:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

     try {
       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
       String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
       cursor.close();
       Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
       Log.e("Path Error", e.toString());
     }
   }
 }
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention I am using Kitkat.  It looks like my problem is KitKat related.  I found this (see below) which helped me get my app working:

[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

Comment: Paste your Logcat Stacktrace here

Comment: are you getting `Intent data` as null??

Comment: @PraveenSharma Can you please help me with this detailed and Bounty added question? It would be really appreciate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-after-nougat-using-retrofit

Answer (score 36):

A little late to the party but here's my code, hope this helps.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData( );
        String picturePath = getPath( getActivity( ).getApplicationContext( ), selectedImageUri );
        Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);
    }
}

public static String getPath( Context context, Uri uri ) {
    String result = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( uri, proj, null, null, null );
    if(cursor != null){
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
            result = cursor.getString( column_index );
        }
        cursor.close( );
    }
    if(result == null) {
        result = "Not found";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ...like a charm. Thanks

Comment: for me not found occured

Comment: @ajaydhadhal getPath will return not found if the image is not saved.  check the uri path and locate the file to see if it exists.

Comment: return "Not found";

Comment: yeah, why is that not found?

Comment: @gumuruh, perhaps your image was never saved in the location you're looking in

Answer (score 17):

Use below code,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     String s = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
     editText1.setText(s);
}
}
```

and below is your getRealPathFromURI function,

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Logcat says this: E/PathError(29354): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_data' does not exist

Comment: if you just want to show full path then use getRealPathFromURI function with your existing code not the full code.

Comment: I have bit edited my code, now it should work, please try again.

Comment: can you post your full activity class code as well as logcat.

Comment: getRealPathFromURI return null always

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
```

And

```
    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your implementation, but this fails too.  This is what I get from logcat:  E/PathError(27809): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class RealFilePath {
    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri     The Uri to query
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id)
                );

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context       The context.
     * @param uri           The Uri to query.
     * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
     public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
            column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
         }
         finally {
             if (cursor != null)
                 cursor.close();
         }
        return null;
    }


   /**
    * @param uri The Uri to check.
    * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
    */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

   /**
    * @param uri The Uri to check.
    * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
    */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

   /**
    * @param uri The Uri to check.
    * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
    */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

   /**
    * @param uri The Uri to check.
    * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
    */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know where this wonderful piece of code came from, but here, on StackOverflow we usually answer a question giving both code, and a reasonable explanation along with it. And ocassionally an url to the original source.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and you dont have a local file ready, for instance you want to give user a chance to take a picture and then upload the picture this is how to do it.
I am a noob in java but i have allot of experience in coding.
Stackoverflow helped me allot so now it is my time to do something back.

Under class activity you have to declare these two items.
asuming you have a working upload class and php script.

> NOTE i am not taking any consideration about all the different API's
>   out there. I am using java compiler 1.7 and a API range of 10 to 18.

```
public class Yourproject extends Activity {
File imageFile;
File imageFileName;

//This part is needed for decoding the path adres.

 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
            String result;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                result = contentURI.getPath();
            } else { 
                cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME); 
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
                cursor.close();
            }
            return result;
        }

//This is needed for the path name, now you might just want to use one decoding script depending on //your class in total.
//In my case this was the way to go.
//To use one single addres use this line ImageColumns.DATA in the int idx declaration.

        private String getRealPathFromNAME(Uri contentNAME) {
            String result;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentNAME, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
                result = contentNAME.getPath();
            } else { 
                cursor.moveToFirst(); 
                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME); 
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
                cursor.close();
            }
            return result;
        }

//Then under protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) you place this code to get 
//the image and process it.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //declare the ImageView
        final ImageView inputPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        inputPicture.setImageURI((Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get("picture"));
        //here where recieve the image from last page "Putextra" method


        try {
            //here we will get the data and proces it trough to get the real 
            //address for uploading.
            //This is send from a other activity with a Intent.EXTRA_STREAM
            //The code looks like this:
            /*********"Putextra"*********/
            //final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            //final Uri thumb = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            //iv.setImageURI(thumb);

            //Sending it to the next activity

            //it.putExtra("picture", thumb);    
            /*********"Putextra"*********/

            Uri fileUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get("picture");
            //get 
            //Uri fileName = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get("picture");
            //get
            imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri));
            //send
            imageFileName = new File(getRealPathFromNAME(fileUri));
            //send
            //i got a exeption Uri fileName, use fileUri twice..
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        //here we will declare the name for furter processing.
        final File uploadFilePath = imageFile;
        final File uploadFileName = imageFileName;


}
```

And the rest i will leave up to u, if you got this far, I am pretty sure you will finish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 file = new File(getPath(outputFileUri));


 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){

    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
    getResources().getString(R.string.select_picture)),GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED);

 }else{

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
      intent.setType("image/jpeg");
      startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
      if (null == data) return;
      Uri originalUri = null;

      if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT_CALLED) {
           originalUri = data.getData();
      } 
      else if (requestCode == GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED) {
           originalUri = data.getData();
           final int takeFlags = data.getFlags()
            & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            // Check for the freshest data.
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri,    takeFlags);
      }
      loadSomeStreamAsynkTask(originalUri);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to get data as well as file path and insert into folder.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            nav = data.getData();
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(nav, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String path= cursor.getString(column_index);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path, 500).show();
            mBitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), nav);
            insert(mBitmap);

            if (mBitmap != null) {  
                mBitmap.recycle();  
                mBitmap = null;  
            } 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void insert(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    File myDir=new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        File dstFile = new File(file.getParent(), "." + file.getName());
        file.renameTo(dstFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```