# how to add image in one fragment and display it in another fragment/pass image through bundle in android

Tags: android

i want to select image in one fragment and display it in another fragment.
how can i do this.

my code is this but not working

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, 100);
        }
    });


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    Uri imageUri;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        file1path = imageUri.getPath();
        TVfrontimg.setText(file1path);
    }
}
```

and i send this using bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("image1", file1path);

registerPartThreeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.replace(R.id.FLcontainer, registerPartThreeFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

in another fragment

```
String imgPath = getArguments().getString("image1");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(new File(imgPath)));
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but its not working.please help.

its giving me this error
2020-05-30 00:16:20.808 8995-8995/com.example.deliveryapp E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /raw/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200319_173033.jpg (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Please use [getDataString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDataString--)() instead of [getData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData--)()

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100){
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());
        //imageUri = data.getData();
        file1path = imageUri.getPath();
        TVfrontimg.setText(file1path);
}
```

And while setting it to the ImageView use ContentResolver and input stream like so:

```
ContentResolver cR = getApplication().getContentResolver();
        try {
            InputStream ip = cR.openInputStream(imageUri);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ip);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

You have to do this because you are getting a contentUri which is different from a file Uri.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have to send image to another fragment. how can i send imageuri to another fragment

Comment: sent it the same way that you do now..using a bundle or you can also use a new instance

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
```

This code you are want showing for image

You should look find real path

Look at answers : [Get filepath and filename of selected gallery image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324155/get-filepath-and-filename-of-selected-gallery-image-in-android)

[android get real path by Uri.getPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath)

Answer (score 0):

In your first fragment

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100){
               val bundle = Bundle()
               bundle.putString("Image",your_image_path)
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_destination_fragment, bundle)
```

}

in second fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
             image= it.getString("Image")
             bitmp= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                    requireActivity().contentResolver,
                     Uri.parse(image)
```

}

and set your bitmap in imageview

imgBitmap.setImageBitmap(bmp)