# Android video file path

Tags: android, video, android-asynctask

I have some code which allegedly finds the path of a previously picked video, in an Async class. I have searched SO and all solutions are similar if not the same, yet the path I get is always null and when I print it the app crashes.

The code is below:

```
 // The file location of the image selected.
            Uri selectedVideo = uris[0];

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            Log.i("INFO", filePath);
            cursor.close();
```

The log errors:

```
12-03 16:47:51.069    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:48:33.884    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:48:48.130  15711-31523/? E/JHEAD﹕ can't open '/0/file:///data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/cache/media_sync/6/6aba39805abcb82-l'
12-03 16:48:48.140  15711-31523/? E/JHEAD﹕ can't open '/0/file:///data/data/com.google.android.apps.plus/cache/media_sync/f/f33ffcaf70cce9-l'
12-03 16:48:50.182      580-649/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Unexpected mtu value: android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@42390b40
12-03 16:48:53.485  31630-31630/? E/PhoneMonitor﹕ onOtaspChanged old =0, new =3
12-03 16:48:58.581    176-31758/? E/AudioSink﹕ received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
12-03 16:48:58.601    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:49:16.510    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:49:16.510    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:49:16.640    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:49:16.640    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:49:26.010    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:49:42.748    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:49:53.629    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:50:04.301    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:50:19.137    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:19.137    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:21.319    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:21.319    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:21.970    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:21.970    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:25.233    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:25.233    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:50:28.997    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:50:38.718    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:50:47.627    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:50:53.473    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:51:07.108    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:51:18.110    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:18.110    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:18.500    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:18.500    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:22.054    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:51:40.073    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:51:47.761    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:47.761    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:48.282    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:48.282    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:51:50.824    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:52:13.869    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:52:17.243    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:52:29.576    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:29.576    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:29.736    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:29.736    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:29.956    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:29.956    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:30.206    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:52:30.206    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:54:45.391    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:54:45.391    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:54:45.681    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:54:45.681    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:54:45.711    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:54:53.630    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:55:03.260    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:55:23.351    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:55:23.351    2644-2644/? E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-03 16:55:25.373    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:55:39.408    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:55:41.240    2644-2644/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-03 16:57:47.005  32440-32440/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.messages.b', referenced from method bgi.<init>
12-03 16:57:47.005  32440-32440/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.render.g', referenced from method bgi.<init>
12-03 16:57:47.015  32440-32440/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.behavior.validation.a', referenced from method bgi.<init>
12-03 16:57:47.015  32440-32440/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.mutation.N', referenced from method bgi.<init>
12-03 16:57:48.226  32521-32521/? E/MY KEY HASH:﹕ PaXGYdYcmTsLk5ibvJIlKJeOkQ8=
12-03 16:57:51.559  32470-32605/com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader, PID: 32470
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:160)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:155)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(S3UploaderActivity.java:123)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-03 16:57:52.060  32470-32470/com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ff97f8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-357,230} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity$S3PutObjectTask.onPreExecute(S3UploaderActivity.java:131)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity.onActivityResult(S3UploaderActivity.java:79)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5435)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3342)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "when I print it the app crashes": post your logs

Comment: Change `Log.i("INFO", filePath);` to `Log.i("INFO", "Path is: " + filePath);` and you will avoid the crash.  But you need to figure out why it is null, perhaps you have not actually found it, or are looking in the wrong column.

Comment: I'm aware of how not to crash the app but the problem is, as you say, that the path is NULL when it shouldn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**:

I'm sure that your code will work on 4.3 and below, but KitKat has some changes. Hope this threads will help:

[Get real path from URI, Android KitKat new storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework)

[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

---

Your code looks correct. Try:

```
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.Data };
```

and, maybe, you should change your query:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo, null, null, null, null);
```

Finally, what is your URI? It may be Dropbox or other similar local file path.

Comment: The changes make no difference...
My URI is- content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A11031

Comment: Which Android version are you using? KitKat?

Comment: Yes I am. Has something changed?