# This is not showing the image in Activity from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I am a beginner and I am unable to find why this is not showing me the image.

```
public void openRecent(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"CHOOSE``FILE"),REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override``
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
``Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try{
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,filePath,null,null,null);
            if(cursor!=null){
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String dString = cursor.getString(colIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dString));
            }
        }


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**This is the error I got in logcat "E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException"**

Comment: please refrain from posting unecessary information such as your skill level.

Comment: This may help :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196378/8321236)

Comment: Thankyou Elysian Apps this really helped.