# Android - Pick and View a file of any type

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to lets users able to pick any file type in their phones, then view it again using intent.

To pick file item I write this ( I'm using Kotlin, same issue in Java):

```
    fun goToDocumentPicker() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        if (intent.resolveActivity(mContext.packageManager) != null)
            mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DOCUMENT)
    }
```

And to show the picked item:

```
 fun showDocumentPreviewer(uri: Uri) {
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        i.data = uri
        mContext.startActivity(i)
    }
```

The document picker works fine, in the `onActivityResult` I can receive the Uri object of selected document, but the document previewer can't open the object. Already try to set mime-type to the previewer's intent but not success. Did I use incorrect way to open file in Android? Any generic way to show any file type in Android? (Because I want to support many file types)

picked Uri:  `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:80`

**Update:**
Base on @CommonsWare's comment, I edited the preview function like below:

```
fun showAttachmentPreviewer(uri: Uri, mimeType: String?) {
    Log.d("TEST", "Preview " + uri.toString())
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

    val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with")
    if (intent.resolveActivity(mContext.packageManager) != null)
        mContext.startActivity(chooser)
    else
        mContext.showSnackBar("No suitable application to open file")
}
```

Now the app always crash with below crash-log:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10202 does not have permission to uri
>   0 @
>   content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio:17915

**Update 2:**
My app crash at line `mContext.startActivity(chooser)`. Here is the full crash-log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: com.makeit.lite, PID: 12851
>                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10477 does not have permission to uri
>   0 @
>   content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:24776
>                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
>                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2514)
>                                                                        at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1494)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3913)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3860)
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4184)
>                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4152)
>                                                                        at
>   com.makeit.lite.attachment.AttachmentNavigator.showAttachmentPreviewer(AttachmentNavigator.kt:92)
>                                                                        at
>   com.makeit.lite.attachment.list.AttachmentListPresenter.onAttachmentClicked(AttachmentListPresenter.kt:37)
>                                                                        at
>   com.makeit.lite.attachment.list.AttachmentListFragment$onViewCreated$1.onItemClick(AttachmentListFragment.kt:39)
>                                                                        at
>   eu.davidea.viewholders.FlexibleViewHolder.onClick(FlexibleViewHolder.java:121)
>                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
>                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

**Update 3:**
If I set mimeType to intent: `intent.type = mimeType` and the app won't crash anymore. The `mimeType` is the string I get from the picker intent (beside the `content:` uri). The mimeType value canbe `image/jpeg` or anything base on selected file type. Although it won't crash, the file at given uri won't display as well. If I choose the `Gallery` from Intent-Chooser, the Gallery open and show all images. I guess the 3rd app don't know how to determinate the file at given uri.

Here is the latest source of my function:

```
fun showAttachmentPreviewer(uri: Uri, mimeType: String?) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Preview " + uri.toString() + " For type" + mimeType)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        intent.type = mimeType //Can be "image/jpeg" or sth corresponding to the filetype.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with")
        if (intent.resolveActivity(mContext.packageManager) != null)
            mContext.startActivity(chooser)
        else
            mContext.showSnackBar("No suitable application to open file")
    }
```

Comment: Is your app crashing? Or the app choosen to display the content scheme? Which language is this?

Comment: My app crash with above crash-log. The language is Kotlin,

Comment: On which statement does it crash? And why dont you add a try-catch block so your app does not crash? Instead you could display a nice toast to the user. Display e.getMessage(). You only have an android tag. Add one for kotlin.

Comment: @greenapps seems you don't understand my situation.  What I want to do is: lets user pick any file(image,pdf,...) and keep into a list. Then, whenever they click on the list-item, call an intent to choose 3rd application to open selected file.
The problem is I can pick any file, and get correctly `content:` uri. But can't use `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` to open those files.
Wrap the lines of code doesn't help to open file anyway.

Comment: please consider to join the chat at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43279439/523325

Comment: Think i understand perfectly what you want. But please tell me wich code line or which statement causes the exception. You still did not tell. And i think its not your app that produces the security exeption but the user choosen app. You do not let the user choose your app is it?

Comment: @greenapps Check my update in the question.

Comment: Indeed you should set a mimetype. Very good to use the one you got from the picker. Now which 3d party app do you use to show the image? And what is the resolution in pixels of the image file? If you choose the Gallery app to show the image then what happens?

Comment: `I guess the 3rd app don't know how to determinate the file at given uri.`. That app maybe does not know how to read data from a content scheme indeed.

Comment: I would use an intent chooser to select 3rd app to open the uri. But it doesnt work. Event if i use Built-in Gallery to pick image, then use itself for viewer.

Comment: `I guess the 3rd app don't know how to determinate the file at given uri.`. No that app does not receive an uri to begin with.

Comment: I finally found my stupid problem, please help to check my description here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43336067/523325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all, I want to say thank-you to @GreenApps, @Ankit, and @CommonsWare. Who spent time to investigate my issue.

I finally found the root cause when extracting the source to separated simple project. It's because I parse uri-string into uri-instance this way (the code of root-cause didn't included in my question. My apologies):

```
val uri = Uri.parse(URLDecoder.decode(uriString, "UTF-8")) as Uri
```

when I changed to `val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)` them problem solved.

Btw, I want to share the sample code for picker and previewer in my Github for someone may need to take a look. The java source is on `master` branch, and the Kotlin source is on `kotlin-version` branch. Using this simple code, now I can pick any file type (image, audio, video, pdf, xlsx,...) and then open it later via Intent.ACTION_VIEW.

Here it is:

> https://github.com/IHNEL/UriPickerPreviewer

Comment: `when I changed to val uri = Uri.parse(item.uri) them problem solved` Why not just `val uri = item.uri;`?

Comment: Good question. I extract the source from my big project. Where I save uri string in entity object, While present to UI, I prepare another view-model object and then have to convert string into uri instance. nvm, will edit the code for easier understand with other viewer

Answer (score 3):

> Did I use incorrect way to open file in Android?

First, there may not be an app capable of viewing the file type.

Second, you have not granted permission for the app to view the content. Use `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: So granted permissions can be forwarded to other apps!? I did not know that  but will investigate soon.

Comment: `there may not be an app capable of viewing the file type.` I would think so as Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE is used.

Comment: I'm sure that there is an app to open that type. Since I pick an image file and it can not open as well.

Comment: @greenapps: "I would think so as Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE is used" -- well, `startActivity()` can throw an `ActivityNotFoundException`. An Android device may not have an app to view an AutoCAD file, or a Photoshop PSD, or lots and lots of other file types.

Comment: @CommonsWare The app always crashes if I set flag `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` as you guided. It throws `java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10202 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:24776`

Can you give me some more hints to make this works? Thanks

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh the issue is well explain [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html) by commonsware himself. as explained in above comments, you have to take care of two different problems. one is file access permission on android 7.0 Nougat and above and second is to check if any activity is present in device that can handle ACTION_VIEW for a given file type. for first problem check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). also, continue...

Comment: with FileProvide you have to apply a sort of patch for pre-lollipop devices that will give file access(read?) permission to all activities which can possibly handle the ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: @greenapps no, afaik it is not possible to forward permission. the permission here that need to be given is for other apps to access the file that belongs to your application. check [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en?fb_comment_id=927823067327697_928849473891723#f29bdd99f5f2078)

Comment: @Ankit, Add an updated code in my question, Already checked for case no app to handle the uri. It crashes even if I pick an image from gallery.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinhdid did you checked my first comment? the error you mentioned is related to android 7.0 and up, reason is similar to NetworkOnMainThreadException. solution is to use FileProvider.

Comment: @Ankit, I checked all your comment and links. But I aware that those aren't my case. As I mentioned, I get the `content: ` uri from an intent and want to open in another intent. I didn't use `file:` uri nor provide my own files. All of them are in external storage.

Since I'm not the owner of selected files, do I really need to read data from input stream then provide via `FileProvider`? 

Sorry if I am too stupid to understand your hint, Since I was being stuck with this more than 1 week and there are a big messy in my head.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141334/discussion-between-nguyen-minh-binh-and-ankit).

Comment: `So granted permissions can be forwarded to other apps!? I did not know that but will investigate soon. `. I'm baffled. Indeed its possible to forward permissions for obtained content scheme uries by just adding a flag.

Comment: @Ankit `afaik it is not possible to forward permission.`. Then please tell CommonsWare. Meanwhile i know it's possible. `the permission here that need to be given is for other apps to access the file that belongs to your application. check this`. Nonsense. That is for file uri exposed exception in Nougat.

Comment: I finally found my stupid problem, please help to check my description here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43336067/523325

Answer (score 3):

```
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
  intent.type = mimeType
```

Change to

```
  val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType (uri, mimeType );
```

You should set uri and mime type with one statement. Otherwise the receiving app will receive null for the uri. Most apps will not tell you that they did not receive an uri. The Gallery app for instance does not.

And i do not know the exact function name for Kotlin.

Comment: No this doesn't help. If I set mimeType separately the app won't crash. If change to set `uri` and `mimeType` same-time, it crash with same crash-log at my question.

Comment: Maybe I will extract the source into simple project on Github so everyone can pulldown to try

Comment: `If change to set uri and mimeType same-time,` You could show how you do that. Or confirm that setDataAndType() exists under Kotlin.

Comment: Yah. I confirm that `setDataAndType` exists under Kotlin and I tried that. And I'm sure that most of functions in Java available in Kotlin (just slightly diff in syntax).

Comment: So if you dont supply an uri you have no exception but the choosen app does not get an uri too.

Comment: Keep using setDataAndType. Anything else does not make sense. Do away with the listview and call the second intent directly from onActivityResult of the first one. Show that code.

Comment: I finally found my stupid problem, please help to check my description here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43336067/523325

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a perfect functionality with the file you should use any third party library for this functionality.

you should check the below link for the most common libraries for the file pickers:-

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created

Comment: I'm ok with the Document Provider which help to pick and return the uri. My question is how to start an intent to view that picked uri