# Cordova 3.4.0: Camera.getPicture() returns encoded URI when selected from GALLERY

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Camera.getPicture() API to capture image or select image from GALLERY.
When I take the picture using camera, it returns me FileEntry having correct URL with filename and extension. But when I select a file from Gallery, it returns "FileEntry.fullPath" as /com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A322 
and sometimes /media/external/images/media/319

What I want is, I want to verify the file type supported(that is jpg/jpeg) and the actual filename.

Is there a way to get the Filename with extension, which is selected.

Thanks in advance.

Code Snippet:

```
        var data = {};
        if( type === CAMERA){
            data = {
                        quality: quality,
                        destinationType: FILE_URI,
                        encodingType: JPEG, targetWidth: 1200, targetHeight: 1200,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                    };
        }
        else
        {
            data = {
                        destinationType: FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: PHOTOLIBRARY,
                        mediaType: ALLMEDIA

                    };
        }


        navigator.camera.getPicture(
                successCallback, errorCallback, data
        );   

      //The success callback method is : 
       successCallback: function(imageURI, param)
       {
                 //HERE THE imageURI value is coming with different format if selected from GALLERY
                 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, 
            function(fileEntry) {fileEntry.file(onSuccess,onError);},
                            function(evt) {onError.call(this,evt.target.error);} );

       }
```

Comment: which android version, and ur cordova version, and your code also

Comment: Android version is 4.2.2 and Cordova is 3.4.0(latest)

Comment: Don't you have the name and extension in imageURI? From what I know when you select from gallery it should look like somepath/resize.jpg?timestamp

Comment: Our existing code was checking for filename(after spliting with /) and extension from imageURI. Which is broken after upgrading Cordova.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to convert from a "content://" URI to a "file://" URI using this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-filepath.

After obtaining the "file://" URI, I'm then able to use Cordova's resolveLocalFileSystemURL() function.

Hope this helps.

```
if (fileUri.startsWith("content://")) {
    //We have a native file path (usually returned when a user gets a file from their Android gallery)
    //Let's convert to a fileUri that we can consume properly
    window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(fileUri, function(localFileUri) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file://" + localFileUri, function(fileEntry) {/*Do Something*/});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in phonegap getpicture method
    navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );

we can give cameraOptions

```
{ quality : 75,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false };
```

check the options first.

**Android Quirks**

Android 4.4 only: Android 4.4 introduced a new Storage Access Framework that makes it easier for users to browse and open documents across all of their preferred document storage providers. Cordova has not yet been fully integrated with this new Storage Access Framework. Because of this, the getPicture() method will not correctly return pictures when the user selects from the "Recent", "Drive", "Images", or "External Storage" folders when the destinationType is FILE_URI. However, the user will be able to correctly select any pictures if they go through the "Gallery" app first. Potential workarounds for this issue are documented on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content/20177611). Please see CB-5398 to track this issue.

Android uses intents to launch the camera activity on the device to capture images, and on phones with low memory, the Cordova activity may be killed. In this scenario, the image may not appear when the Cordova activity is restored.

If you got fileEntry you can use file() method to get mettadatas

```
 function cameraSuccess(urls) {

       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(){

                    // alert('success requestFileSystem');

                 }, function(){
                 //error

                   });

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(urls, function(fileEntry){


                   fileEntry.file(function(file){

                             // alert(JSON.stringify(file)); //view full metadata
                                var type = file.type;
                                var nameoffile = file.name;

                               }, function(){

                                //error                                                 
                                });

                  },function(){

                 // error 
                  } );
```

One Last option is to create one custom plugin for finding type of image

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works fine for PictureSourceType:Camera, If I select a file from GALLERY, it is returning FieEntry with a different kind of URL which does not have filename and extension in it.

Comment: I alerted the JSON string for the file object. file.name is "content" always and file.type is "image/jpeg". So I can use file type here.But I wont be getting filename. I have to send the file with different name to server. Or as you said I need to look into file or camera plugins or need to implement new plugin.