# How to get actual path to video from onActivityResult

Tags: android, video, uri, filepath

I have a video that I save to `.../Movies/MyApp/abcde.mp4`. So I know where it is. When I load it through my app using an implicit intent to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, the path is returned as `content:/media/external/video/media/82` when I do

```
data.getData().toString()
```

The problem with that path is that it works when I try to access it with MediaRecorder as

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mVideoStringPath))
```

However if I try to convert it to a path in another thread (for a job queue), the file is not found

```
new File(mVideoStringPath)
```

when I use the technique (copy and paste) described at [How to get file path in onActivityResult in Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841235/how-to-get-file-path-in-onactivityresult-in-android-4-4), still get the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid image file
```

Also per my logging, the new technique shows the path to the video as

```
video path: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/MyApp/abc de.mp4
```

notice the space in `abc de.mp4`. that indeed is the name of the file. And the phone's camera app has no trouble playing

Answer (score 0):

> However if I try to convert it to a path in another thread (for a job queue), the file is not found

That is because it is not a path to a file. It is a `Uri`, which is an opaque handle to some data.

> How to get actual path to video from onActivityResult

You don't. You use the `Uri`. There is no requirement that the `Uri` point to a file. There is no requirement that the `Uri`, if it happens to represent a file, represent one that you have direct filesystem access to.

Answer (score -2):

you need to escape the space the the file path in order to construct a File object from it.

```
filepath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```