# Easy and universal way to get filename shared with ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I'm receiving intents sent with default share mechanism (ACTION_SEND) from different applications.

If it is a file – I need to copy it.
I don't need a full path to file since I can open it directly with a stream.

```
InputStream input = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
```

---

But I need to know a filename to save file properly.

**Is there any easy and universal way to get a filename of the shared file not paying attention to the content type (it can be image from gallery, video, files from downloads)?**

---

Or should I use something like this to get the full path from the uri and then get filename from it?

[Get real path from URI, Android KitKat new storage access framework [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework)
[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

---

Also I saw this article ([A Uri Is Not (Necessarily) a File](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html)) and there is said:

> You can perform the following operations on such Uri values:
>
> - Find out their DISPLAY_NAME and SIZE — the OpenableColumns — via a query() on the Uri (again, using a ContentResolver, or in theory a
>   CursorLoader)

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MediaStore interface the DISPLAY_NAME column is indeed delivered.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

projection contains DISPLAY_NAME

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    // get your file name
}
```

I have not tested it but it should work ;-)