# Get image path from android gallery kitkat for unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gallery

I am making a library for unity that can pick image from android gallery and can show in unity. how can i get the path of image of android gallery for kitkat?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a plugin for that. Here is some code to get image path:

```
private static void processImageFromGallery(Intent intent) {
    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,
            null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Is this for Kitkat ? this is not working for kitkat version. :(

Comment: I'm not sure. I implemented that time ago and haven't tested it lately again. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content