# Load file from external storage using chooser

Tags: android, file

So, I'm trying to load a simple .txt file like this:

```
    private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And of course, catching the result like this:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri uri = data.getData();
```

It works great on genymotion and on my device if I use a file explorer that I have installed (File explorer, see image abovew), now, If use the chooser directly like this:

[image]

It says it cannot find the specified file. (FileNotFoundException)

Now, I've realized that the URIs I get from these two file choosers are different

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ffile.txt <- THIS DOESNT WORK (android built in explorer)
>
> content://media/external/file/44751 <- THIS WORKS (custom explorer)

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting different URIs for the SAME file.

**EDIT:**
I tried to use a content resolver to get the file path from the URI like this:

```
public class Utils {

public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(proj[0]);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Still no luck :(

Comment: Oh, I had same problem before.
Maybe this answer may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content

I hope for your good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use a content resolver to get the file path from the URI like this

There is no file path. [A `Uri` does not necessarily point to a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html) that you can access on your local filesystem, just as the URL to this Web page does not necessarily point to a file that you can access on your local filesystem. The `Uri` might:

- represent a file held in internal storage of the other app
- represent a BLOB column value in a database
- represent a file held in "the cloud", to be downloaded when requested
- etc.

Use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()` to read in the content represented by the `Uri`, just like you would use `HttpUrlConnection` to read in the content represented by the URL for this Web page. `openInputStream()` takes the `Uri` as a parameter and returns an `InputStream`. You would use that `InputStream` the same way you would any other `InputStream` (e.g., `FileInputStream`, `InputStream` from `HttpUrlConnection`). The exact mechanics of that will depend a lot on the underlying data (e.g., [read in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string), pass to `BitmapFactory` to decode a `Bitmap`).

Comment: Yup, I've seen your comments on other stackoverflow posts and fixed my code, check out the "edited" part of my question

Comment: @feresr: The edited part of your question is your problem. Get rid of `getRealPathFromURI()`. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content represented by the `Uri`.

Comment: oh, thanks. let me try that, I'll get back to you :)

Comment: "Or, perhaps do the inverse: try to open a stream on the Uri, and if that fails, then see if the _DATA pattern is in play." Do you happen to have an example on how to do this? (open a stream on the Uri)

Comment: @feresr: "open a stream on the Uri" -- as I wrote twice previously, and will now put in boldface to perhaps help with readability, **use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content represented by the `Uri`**. You know how to get a `ContentResolver`, as that is in your code in your question. `openInputStream()` takes one parameter: the `Uri` to open. You get an `InputStream` back, just as you get an `InputStream` to read in data from a Web server via `HttpUrlConnection`, or you get an `InputStream` to read in data from a local file via `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I carefully read your comment and I knew what you meant, I just didn't know HOW to go about doing so. I've updated your answer with the code to read from the inputstream, if you think it's OK, please leave a comment so I can mark this answer as the accepted one. Thanks!.

Comment: @feresr: I added more clarity, including a link to a popular SO question on reading in text from an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

@CommonsWare's asnwer must be the right way of solving this, but I'm not sure how to implement his solution.
I've ended up doing what @Paul Burke recomends on this link:

[Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

**EDIT**

For my particular case, this is how my code ended up. I leave this here for future reference. (I'm using @CommonsWare's explanation) see his answer above.

```
               try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            text.append(line);
                            text.append("\n");
                        }
                    } else {
                        subscriber.onError(new InputException("There's something seriously wrong with this file"));
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
```