# Import local JSON file and parse in Android Kotlin programmatically

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, import

I'm using Android Studio, with Kotlin class. My app needs and module which imports local JSON file in device and parse it. I've been struggling to solve this.

the local JSON name is data.json, file contains
...
{"name": "Dame", "age": "23","gender": "female" }
...

Comment: You will need a Json parser. Might refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/   i can parse easily. But loading a json file to parse I'm finding difficulty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981292/load-file-from-external-storage-using-chooser