# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission needed while using storage access framework in android

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I was using `Storage Access Framework` to access images and using them in my app. I read it somewhere that when using the `SAF`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is not needed to read from internal storage, SD Cards, or anything else. The Android System is the one accessing the storage, so applications do not need direct access and that this is in fact one of the major selling points of the SAF. 
But running my app without requesting for the read permission results in crashing of the app and gives an error saying:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media, requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`

Following is the code for building an intent for the same:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

And here is the code within the `onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)` callback:

```
if (data != null) {
                    avatarImageUri = data.data
                    image_avatar.setImageURI(avatarImageUri)
                    avatarImage = File(getPath(context!!, avatarImageUri!!))
                    isAvatarChanged = true
                    imageObservable.onNext(isAvatarChanged)
                }
```

I'm simply trying to use an image selected from SAF and set it into the `image_avatar` view.

Can anybody help me with this and tell me if SAF actually requires permissions to be provided explicitly?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are getting this `Uri` and how you are using it. For example, are you saving the `Uri` somewhere, then trying to use it in some future process or component?

Comment: Please give manifest permission **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
And check same for [run time permission](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/).**

Comment: @CommonsWare, just edited the question.

Comment: Delete `avatarImage = File(getPath(context!!, avatarImageUri!!))`, because [a `Uri` is not a `File`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221353/115145). Beyond that, what is the complete Java stack trace, and what lines of code in your app are mentioned in that stack trace?

Comment: `avatarImage` is a file type which I will be using later on for some api request

Comment: [A `Uri` is not a `File`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221353/115145). If you want a `File`, do not use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Use [a file-picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created). Or, adapt your API request to work with an `InputStream`, which you can get by calling `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` on some `Context`. That does not explain the error message, though, which is why I am hoping that you can provide the complete Java stack trace.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Rv5qheVn - here is a complete stacktrace

Comment: Also the `getPath` function that I am using to convert uri to file was obtained from the following answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208911/get-realpath-return-null-on-android-marshmallow

Comment: That `getPath()` method never worked well, and it certainly does not work on modern versions of Android.

Comment: But it works well when read and write permissions are provided, but then one of the benefits of using SAF is being hampered. Can you provide any other alternative way to convert such content based uri's to files @CommonsWare?

Comment: "But it works well when read and write permissions are provided" -- only on the things you tested. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` works with arbitrary document providers, such as Windows file servers, Google Drive/other cloud storage providers, etc. Your permission hack will not work with those, because [**a `Uri` is not a `File`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221353/115145). Use the `InputStream`. In a pinch, copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to some file that you control. Or, better yet, **stop using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` if you are only willing to support files**.