# In ACTION_GET_CONTENT, unable to resolve Uri to full file path, if 3rd party file explorer app is used

Tags: android

Currently, I let user pick a zip file by using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/zip");
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.REQUEST_CHOOSE_BACKUP_FILE);
```

In `onActivityResult`, we are getting `Uri` through `data.getData()`

I'm using [Paul Burke's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559418/72437), to resolve `Uri` to full file path.

It works well till I use a [3rd party Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer) (You can see the blue file cabinet icon. The app name is Explorer)

[image]

An example of returned Uri is  **content://com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer.content/storage/emulated/0/Download/epayslip-2.zip** , if I select a file through Explorer.

By using Paul Burke's code, `getDataColumn` will be executed, which it will eventually return null.

I was wondering, is this caused by shortcoming of Paul Burke's code, or the problem is lied on the implementation of 3rd party file explorer app? Is it possible that we can fix it?