# How to create files using URI from external sd?

Tags: android, uri

Basically, my question is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128077/android-opening-a-file-with-action-get-content-results-into-different-uris/36129285), and I've used the solution given to that. The problem is, it will only work if the file came from the internal storage, and this is the cause of it:

in this part of the code (in the solution in the question I mentioned):

```
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
```

there is no following **else** statement. I've searched for ways to access that **non-primary volumes** but I can't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code supplied in that question and answer are **awful**. There is no requirement for the `Uri` to point to a file, let alone a file that you can access, let alone a file whose path you can derive from the `Uri` itself. A `Uri` with a `content` scheme is an opaque handle, nothing more.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` (or `openOutputStream()`) to get a stream on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: yes, I think I've read your comment somewhere about this. But I'll try that openInputStream that you mentioned then I'll give an update.