# How Can I Get the Uri of Image if I Open the Gallery and Select Image and share with my App

Tags: android, image, uri, gallery

How Can I Get the Uri of Image if I Open the Gallery and Select Image and share with my App, but Image is not showing in ImageView

Answer (score 1):

Open gallery for getting Image Uri

```
 private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;

  private void handleOpenGallery() {
        Intent intentSelect = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intentSelect.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentSelect, getString(R.string.select_picture)),
                REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
```

Uri of selected Image

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            shareImage(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Share Image

```
  private void shareImage(Uri imageUri) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below code by Raghu to open gallery,

if you only want to open gallery then you can use,

`Intent intentSelect = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);`

Add check for read/write permissions if OS version is above Marshmallow(6.0)

If you still don't get the uri then in onActivityResult when you will fetch the uri [try the getPath method from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129285/5466486)

Add check if the Android OS version is above Nougat(7.0) or not, as above nougat while fetching file uri you may get "FileUriExposedException" [refer this link for more info](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)