# Android - Picker to select multiple videos

Tags: android

I've tried using a simple Activity to select multiple videos, but the file paths I get are always null. Even though I get the URI like :

"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A86935"

I cannot convert this into a filePath. With the code below, "videoPath is null" will be always printed.

```
public class VideoPickerActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoPickerActivity";

    private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 1;

    private List<String> selectedVideos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/mp4");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select videos"), SELECT_VIDEO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
                selectedVideos = getSelectedVideos(data);
            }
        }
        finish();
    }

    private List<String> getSelectedVideos(Intent data) {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

        // Single video selected
        if(data.getData() != null){

            Uri mImageUri = data.getData();

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String videoPath  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            if(videoPath == null)
                Log.e(TAG, "videoPath is null");
            result.add(videoPath);
            cursor.close();
        }
        // Multiple videos selected
        else {
            ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
            if (mClipData != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                    ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    if (cursor == null)
                        Log.e(TAG, "cursor is null");
                    else {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                            String videoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            if(videoPath == null)
                                Log.e(TAG, "videoPath is null");
                            result.add(videoPath);
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "cannot use cursor");
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've managed to do it based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559418/5120292)

Here is the code I've used :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VideoPickerActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoPickerActivity";

    private static final int SELECT_VIDEOS = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_VIDEOS_KITKAT = 1;

    private List<String> selectedVideos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/mp4");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select videos"),SELECT_VIDEOS);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setType("video/mp4");
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_VIDEOS_KITKAT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            selectedVideos = getSelectedVideos(requestCode, data);
        }
        finish();
    }

    private List<String> getSelectedVideos(int requestCode, Intent data) {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
        if(clipData != null) {
            for(int i=0;i<clipData.getItemCount();i++) {
                ClipData.Item videoItem = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                Uri videoURI = videoItem.getUri();
                String filePath = getPath(this, videoURI);
                result.add(filePath);
            }
        }
        else {
            Uri videoURI = data.getData();
            String filePath = getPath(this, videoURI);
            result.add(filePath);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); if you want to open straight into the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

This is also working

```
// Start The Mutli Image Picker Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

intent.setType("video/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,
                true);

final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 206;

activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                                     "Select Picture"),
                                RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: mime types play a role here