# null poiner on select image from gallery on API 19

Tags: android, exception, android-intent

I'm very new in android. I don't know why I got this null pointer exception.I run my program on API 17 and it was performed without any problems but when I'm running on API 19 I got Null pointer Exception.
in my app I just select an image from gallery and image's URI is saved in Database.all this happens in Fragment.
manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sayres.myapplication7">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".mvp.view.MainListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".mvp.view.profile.ProfileActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

my fragment class:

```
package com.example.sayres.myapplication7.mvp.view.profile;


 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import com.example.sayres.myapplication7.App;
 import com.example.sayres.myapplication7.R;
 import com.example.sayres.myapplication7.entity.Contact;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

 /**
  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
  */
public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private EditFragmentCallBack editFragmentCallBack;
private EditText fragmentEditEditTextName;
private EditText fragmentEditEditTextFamily;
private EditText fragmentEditEditTextPhoneNumber;
private static final int SELECT_FILE = 0;
public static final String TAG = "====>";
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private Uri selectedImageUri;
private CircleImageView fragmentEditPicture;
private Bitmap bm;
private Button fragmentEditBtUpdate;
private int id;
private int rowUpdate;
private String name;
private String family;
private String phoneNumber;
private Contact contact;


public EditProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttach: is running");

    editFragmentCallBack = (EditFragmentCallBack) context;
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttach: editFragmentCallBack was initialized");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView- EditFragment: is running");
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
    initFragment(fragmentView);
    return fragmentView;
}


private void initFragment(View parent) {

    /**
     * referencing of  fragment_edit_profile
     */
    fragmentEditPicture = (CircleImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_picture);
    fragmentEditEditTextName = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_editText_name);
    fragmentEditEditTextFamily = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_editText_family);
    fragmentEditEditTextPhoneNumber = (EditText) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_editText_phone);
    fragmentEditBtUpdate = (Button) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_btn_save);


    fragmentEditBtUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: yess");
            id = contact.get_id();
            name = fragmentEditEditTextName.getText().toString();
            family = fragmentEditEditTextFamily.getText().toString();
            phoneNumber = fragmentEditEditTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: name " + name);
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: family " + family);


            contact = new Contact(id, name, family, phoneNumber, selectedImageUri.toString());
            rowUpdate = App.getInstanceImplementation().updateContact(contact);

            Log.i("==>", "btnUpdateContact: " + rowUpdate);

        }
    });


    /**
     * get contact by invoke from CallBack on ProfileActivity
     */
    contact = editFragmentCallBack.getContact();

    fragmentEditEditTextName.setText(contact.getName());
    fragmentEditEditTextFamily.setText(contact.getFamily());
    fragmentEditEditTextPhoneNumber.setText(contact.getPhonNumber());


}



public void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Choose from Library", "Cancel"};
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Add Photo ");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);


            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {

            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        }
    }
}


public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        bm = null;

        try {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "selectedImageUri " + selectedImageUri);


        Bitmap photoBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 40, 40, true);
        fragmentEditPicture.setImageBitmap(photoBitMap);
    }

}


public interface EditFragmentCallBack {
    Contact getContact();

    void finishProfile();

}

 }
```

Exception:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.sayres.myapplication7, PID: 17962
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65536, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/139137_(2560x1600).JPG }} to activity {com.example.sayres.myapplication7/com.example.sayres.myapplication7.mvp.view.profile.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:590)
                                                                                   at com.example.sayres.myapplication7.mvp.view.profile.EditProfileFragment.onSelectFromGalleryResult(EditProfileFragment.java:196)
                                                                                   at com.example.sayres.myapplication7.mvp.view.profile.EditProfileFragment.onActivityResult(EditProfileFragment.java:171)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:176)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the exception occur `onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);` and `Bitmap photoBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 40, 40, true);`
 line

Comment: A question here..#1: What the value of `selectedImageUri` being obtained?

Comment: if i understand correctly, selectedImageUri is initialized when i select an image from gallery and when I click on the button, image's uri added to the database

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned updated `onSelectFromGalleryResult()` method:

```
public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        bm = null;

        try {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            //DON'T USE data.getData() AS IS
            //bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            //REPLACE IT WITH BELOW
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse("file://"+selectedImageUri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "selectedImageUri " + selectedImageUri);


        Bitmap photoBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 40, 40, true);
        fragmentEditPicture.setImageBitmap(photoBitMap);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I fix this problem by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834842/android-gallery-on-kitkat-returns-different-uri-for-intent-action-get-content)

the problem was because of Intent in API<19 and >19.