# How to get the file path of the document attached from Android File Manager

Tags: android, document

I am trying to attach the document from Android default File Manager and Uploading to server.But not able to get the path of file.Its giving the path as 
"Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=6 flg=0x1 }"

How to convert it into proper path so that it provides proper path with file name.
Already Tried with :

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID };

        Cursor fileCursor = baseActivity.getContentResolver().query(
                uri, columns, null,
                null, null );
        fileCursor.moveToFirst();
        int column_index = fileCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

        return fileCursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)

Answer (score 1):

i will share with you the best solution i have found it

```
 public String getRealPathFromUri(final Uri uri) {
        // DocumentProvider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(getActivity(), uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(getActivity(), contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(getActivity(), contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(getActivity(), uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                 String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: i have 2 years experience with android but sometimes i face those problems of Intent, video..

Comment: its not working when i add any document like pdf,doc xls etc

Comment: any update for the same..it works fine for images and videos but not for ducument support

Comment: The `DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)` in `DownloadProvider` is no longer a number. So the `Long.valueOf(id)` will throw exception.

Comment: for the Long.valueOf(id) issue you can go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/53909567/6676659