# Implementing Simple FileProvider

Tags: android

I'm having trouble following the FileProvider and ContentProvider resources, because I don't know what parts are relevant to my situation.

I have 2 flavors set up in gradle, a free and a paid version.

I want the paid version to be able to load files from the free version (as in, they use the free version, then buy the paid version). I should only need to do this once, since I can then save them "locally".  It's always going to be the same files, so I know the content path in advance.  The files are .txt, if that helps.

In the free version, I am granting access to 3 files like this:

```
grantUriPermission("paid_app_packagename",contentUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Am I able to then do everything else (assuming I have the contentUris) from within the paid version, and if so, how?  All of the tutorials involve a file picking system in another activity.

Thanks in advance for your help!

I think I've found a solution (although I'm currently getting permission errors, at least it's progress!), thanks to a fresh mind, and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657557/3630524