# GetRealPathFromUri always get null result

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to get real path from Uri(Of selected image from gallery) but This function returns always null value :

```
//Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {

        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {

        if (cursor != null) {

            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the image you're selecting is not physically available on the device.

Images from gallery or other choose can come from different sources that does not provide a physical file, like a cloud storage for example.

Check this code here on how to open the `Uri` as a `InputStream` that can be used to create a copy of the file (or just read directly).

[Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri)

**edit:**

I'm doing some extra research on it, apparently it also varies on *how* you request this Uri.

if you request it like this (which is the current preferred method as per Android guides):

```
 i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 i.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_STORAGE);
```

and it opens the KitKat style *unified* selector, if you choose an image from there, it will always return null. If you open the left-drawer menu, select the gallery (or a file browser), and pick an image from there, then, if it is a local file image, you will have the correct path.

on the other hand, if you request it like this (which is the old method):

```
 i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 i.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_STORAGE);
```

it will directly open the Gallery, and again, if it is a local file image, you will have the correct path.

So yeah, I still don't believe there's a way to force local only, but at least you have more information to make an informed decision on your coding.

Comment: So is there any way to show only the images available on the device ?

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen this option. I believe that if you want to impose this limitation the only way is to create your own "photo choose". But please, if you find a way of doing it, share with us.

Comment: Now I'm gona use your solution because I'm don't have much time but  in future I'm will try to make this and share it. Also can I get your mail ?

Comment: hi. I edit my answer with some extra information might be useful.

Comment: Thank's a Lot it really was very helpful :)

Comment: Interesting hack-a-round, but then it will also allow multiple file selection. If that's fine for your application, great.

Comment: Sorry, I meant intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true); to allow only local file

Comment: It seems that at the end u answer your own question :) I did some quick test here and it seems to work for the `ACTION_PICK` but the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` seems to still not pass along a file path. =/

Comment: (I'should have  +1 :D)Thank's really your answer was verry helpfull and great  and for ACTION_GET_CONTENT I will check it also