# Unable to get RealPath from URI for video

Tags: android

I am using a button to pick videos from device like

```
dStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("video/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_VIDEO);
            }
        });
```

Then in the `onActivityResult` I have something like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case SELECT_VIDEO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                    final String realPath = selectedVideo.getPath();
                 }
                break;
        }
    }
```

The `realPath` which I need is the location to the file in the device like `/directory/subdirectory/myVideo.mp4`. I have tried a lot of posts previously from `stackoverflow` itself. All results lead to the value of `realPath` as `null`. The posts which I tried are

1. [GetRealPathFromUri always get null result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113357/getrealpathfromuri-always-get-null-result)
2. [Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore)
3. [Get Real Path For Uri Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546101/get-real-path-for-uri-android)

So if you know any way that works, suggest me below. Dont mark as duplicate and other stuff. I know nothing is working.

Comment: `The realPath which I need is the location to the file in the device like /directory/subdirectory/myVideo.mp4.`. You did not tell why. Please tell.

Comment: `final String realPath = selectedVideo.getPath();`. Did you say that realPath==null? If not, what is it?

Comment: i need in that format, with the real path not the content uri. The selectedVideo.getPath() returns some other value. I need the real path.If you have any solution, please share.

Comment: `I need the real path.`. You did not tell why. Please tell.

Comment: `selectedVideo.getPath() ` Other value? Please tell what it returns.

Comment: You did not tell that you use Lollipop. Do you? Try to pick a picture and you will se the same.

Comment: I need the realpath to send the FFMPEG to edit the video, I think you can suggest me how do I get that done, more than worrying about why I need it ?

Comment: You also did not tell which Android target version you are compiling for.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns you the real path from the contentUri of the video.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {

        String res = "";
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                res = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cursor is null");
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: In which device you are getting this error? In every device or in a particular device?

Comment: Nexus - 5 (Lollipop - 5.1)