# Android: the exact location of content:\\

Tags: android, android-file

I'm looking for the path mentioned as below:

```
private static final String STOCK_BOOKMARKS_CONTENT = "content://browser/bookmarks";
private static final String CHROME_BOOKMARKS_CONTENT = "content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks";
```

Where is the exact physical location of these paths on my Android mobile phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Content URIs** are not (necessarily) file system paths. They are a representation defined by the content providers to serve data to whoever requests it without revealing the actual source of data, in a way.

The Content URI's are generally in the following form :

`content://authority/path/id`

Where

`content` - the first part (here `content`) is the scheme of the URI. It could be anything like `file` for File Uri's.

`authority` - The name of the content provider , i.e. the content provider uses this part to identify content uri's meant for them and not for some other content provider.

`path` & `id` - these are defined by the content providers to (generally) identify the exact location of data in their data store (local database, some rest api etc)

Interestingly, Content providers provide a way to get a hold of an InputStream for the content represented by a ContentURI - using `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`

Related

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html
- [Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri)

Answer (score 0):

It depends of Device and system, purpose of "content" is abstraction of files location

Comment: The app is reading bookmarks from these locations. However, I'm not sure where are the bookmarks stored physically. I cannot find them. For the default browser of the mobile the path looks correct. For the Chrome it doesn't work.