# DownloadManager notification click intent issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager

I download content through downloadManager in my app. When download completed and user click notification, my app open.

starting download:

```
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setMimeType(context.getString(R.string.application_mime_type))
                .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.download_title))
                .setDescription(videoName)
                .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,
                        MY_CONTENT_PATH,
                        getFileNameForContent(id, videoName, videoType))
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        manager.enqueue(request)
```

catch notification click:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="@string/application_mime_type" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

MainActivity onCreate():

```
val dataUri = intent.data
    if (dataUri != null) {
        ...
    }
```

For API 19 
`dataUri = file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.mycompany.myapp/files/filename.mp3` 
For API 25 
`dataUri=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/276`

My question: it difference depends on android version or device? Where can i find documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of android version, the behavior is different after API 19.
You can get more information here:

[Android: Getting a file URI from a content URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri)