# Image URI returning null even though the path is correct

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access the Image URI of an image from gallery like this. But when trying to access the image, the file is always null and throws file not found exception.

```
private void GetImage(){ 
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            pickPhoto.setType("image/*");

            //one can be replaced with any action code
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch (requestCode){
        case 1:
            //Gallery
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                setPicforGallery(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
      }
}

private void setPicforGallery(Uri selecteduri) {


    int targetW = 200;
    int targetH = 200;

    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(selecteduri,
            this);

    try {
        imageBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(picturePath,targetW,targetH);
    }
    catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cannot convert to bitmap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(imageBitmap == null){
        Log.v("image","image bitmap is null");
    }

}



public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight)
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth)
    {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

}


public static String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI, Activity context) {
    String result = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( contentURI, proj, null, null, null );
    if(cursor != null){
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
            result = cursor.getString( column_index );
        }
        cursor.close( );
    }
    if(result == null) {
        result = "Not found";
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code is just pretty much testing if the image is null with the given Uri and its always hitting there. 
I had this working at one point and now I dont know why I am always getting this error.

I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to the permissons in android manifest file as well.

Please help.

Here is the error log

```
01-31 03:58:27.251 13944-13944/XXXX.XXXX.XX E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180123_191544.jpg (No such file or directory)
01-31 03:58:27.252 13944-13944/com.XXX.XXXX E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180123_191544.jpg (No such file or directory)
01-31 03:58:27.252 13944-13944/XXX.XXXXXt V/image: image bitmap is null
01-31 03:58:27.257 13944-13944/XXX.XXXXXD/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-31 03:58:27.260 13944-13944/XXX.XXXXXE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.XXXX.XXXX, PID: 13944
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/98/ORIGINAL/NONE/2117678506 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F98/ORIGINAL/NONE/2117678506} }} to activity {com.XXX.XXXXX/XXX.XXXXXt.Addjob2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4323)
```

Comment: Please add log.

Comment: on what android version you are testing? @alan

Comment: do not use any `getRealPathFromURI` method - it will not work, instead read `ContentResolver` documentation on how to get `InputStream` from given `Uri`

Comment: Add your logcat.

Comment: @pskink is correct, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri

Comment: @Ankur_009 Im using the emulator. Android 8.0.0 API 26.

Comment: @Ankur_009 it is not important what android version it is, the `ContentResolver` works from API level 1

Comment: I tried using ContentResolver to get the URI, but I still get a FileNotFound Exception

Comment: @pskink I didn't see your comment.   try to check the permission. Ask runtime permission.

Comment: `I tried using ContentResolver to get the URI` ??? Strange. You used ACTION_PICK to get that uri. After that you can use the contentresover to get an input stream. Please show that code.

Comment: please use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to avoid null URI's

Comment: In your case getRealPathFromUri() did work. You got a nice path on external storage. You requested read permission in manifest. But that is not enough for Android 6+. You are already told what to do if you want to continue with that path.

Answer (score 0):

you can see following tutorials:
http://en.proft.me/2017/07/1/how-get-image-gallery-or-camera-android/