# Android: How to share a contact via intent?

Tags: android, share, contacts

how can i share a Android contact using an intent?

I tried like this, but somehow i guess i have to forward the contact id in a different way:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(con.id));
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i share a Android contact using an intent?

It is unlikely that you can. A contact is a series of database records, and as such cannot usually be shared via `ACTION_SEND`.

Moreover, you do not use `setData()` with `ACTION_SEND`. Usually, you set `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM` to be the text or `Uri` to share, and set the MIME type of the `Intent` to be the MIME type of the content in `EXTRA_TEXT` (`text/plain`) or `EXTRA_STREAM`. You may wish to review [the documentation on `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) for other alternatives.

My guess is that few apps will agree to share a contact, and those that do will crash when they try, as the `Uri` in `EXTRA_STREAM` is supposed to represent a stream (e.g., a file served by `FileProvider`), not a database-style entry.

You might consider generating some text or HTML that represents the contact, then sharing it, as that is more likely to be successful (e.g., to send in an email). Or, you could try standard contact encoding formats, like vCard, and see if that works.

Comment: Somehow it has to be possible! I can choose a share action on my real device (Android 4.4.4) for each contact. If i choose 'Gmail' for example, a *.vcf file will be automatically attached to the resulting email.

Comment: @nr1: A .vcf file is a file representing a contact, not a contact itself. In particular, a .vcf file is a [vCard file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), which I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you show how to export the contact's data (whatever is possible) into VCF file, and share it? Is this a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701727/extract-contact-list-in-vcf-format/8701774#8701774 ?