# How to take contact backup using code?

Tags: android, backup, android-contacts

As we all know that, when we click the option "export to SD card" in contacts, , It means we are creating our contact backup and that file is stored with the extension as a .VCF file format, Later on when we import that file, android OS automatically takes all the contacts in it and saves in our contacts. I just want to create that .VCF (A Contacts backup file) using code.

Comment: is this what u want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file

Comment: Hey Brother Thanks a lot dear...Yeah...this is the one I was looking for....Thanks again.

Comment: See my answer given in this link : Perfect running code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file/13560584#13560584

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export the Contacts as VCF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file)

Answer (score 0):

[vcardio](http://code.google.com/p/vcardio/) is an open-source application that does exactly what you've put as your description. I'd check it out and tweak it if necessary.

Comment: Dear HD1, you can go through my edited code on this link, Its 200% working for getting all the contacts in .VCF file Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file/13560584#13560584

Comment: Aside from the mathematical impossibility of a probability of "200%", thank you for the code sample, except I wasn't the one asking the question. Leave it as an answer for OP to accept.

Comment: This is new era when people can cheat for more than 1000 crore...then sure I can guarantee for 200%....and as we are engineers.....anything is possible...Proud to be Engineer... :):):)..

Comment: Sorry, mate, outside India, people don't cheat.

Comment: That's really true..Agree.. :(:(:(