# export contacts from listview of my application

Tags: android

i want to copy just the checked contacts to sd card as a vcf file

Is there any way to copy the checked contacts from a list view to s d card ? i have made an app in which i can export contacts from the contacts menu but i want to export contacts from a list view and which are checked contacts.please kindly help. i have to submit a project.

```
itemsSelected = "Selected items: \n";
for (int i = 0; i < lstContacts.getCount(); i++) {
    view = lstContacts.getChildAt(i);                   
    check=   (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    if (check.isChecked()) {
        itemsSelected += lstContacts.getItemAtPosition(i) + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can save them in csv/txt file on sd card.

Comment: how can we add them? can you please elaborate?

Comment: Here you will find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147563/export-the-contacts-as-vcf-file

Comment: What have you done so far? First you try post it here then we will help you out. Without trying how can you expect help?

Comment: In above comment I gave you hint, google it still unable to solve. I'll help you

Comment: thanks erowlin. but you are not getting my question. i have exported all the contacts from that link only. but now i want to export only the checked contacts which are in the listview. i have added all the contacts in a listview with a checkbox.now i want to copy from that listview to a sd card. thanks in advance

Comment: @rit- i have tried a lot. i am stuck from last 2 days. i have done from the above link only. please help me

Comment: i have searched on google also.but i cant find it. @Rit - Are u getting my question or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer to this question. 
in this,lv is the contactlist from listview. just copy this code and you can check the contacts which you want to copy to the sd card.

```
long [] ids = lv.getCheckedItemIds();
         for(long id : ids) {
             Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);

phones.moveToFirst();
for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
{
  String lookupKey =    phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
AssetFileDescriptor fd;
 try 
 {

     fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
     fis = fd.createInputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
     fis.read(buf);
     String VCard = new String(buf);


     //private File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//yourdir//");
      sdCard =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//yourdir//");
      directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
     directory.mkdirs();
     file = new File(directory, vfile);




     // String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
     FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
     mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());        

     phones.moveToNext(); 
    //Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);
 } 
 catch (Exception e1) 
 {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();
 }

 }}
Toast.makeText(this, "contacts copied to  " + vfile, 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```