# getting NegativeByteArraySizeException from ContentResolver's openAssetFileDescriptor method for reading vCardUri. Is there any workaround to fix it?

Tags: file-descriptor, android-7.0-nougat, android-contentresolver

I am creating a .VCF file for backing up the Contacts. The process of creating and inserting the data get failed because of the `FileDescriptor's` method `getDeclaredLength` which returns the size `-1` for the length of the `vCard-URI` which I got from the `ContentResolver's` `openAssetFileDiscritor` method.

This is the exact same Question as [asked here by Balakrishna Avulapati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017591/in-android-7-contentresolvers-method-openassetfiledescriptorvcarduri-r-re/42020832#42020832?newreg=7295992cdc074fa5ae4e5b0d0a56d104). but the only problem for asking the same question here is that, the proposed solution is a bit hard for me to understand. which do not salve my problem. The comment by **@pskink** in the solution of above link could be useful but i am anable to find the full source code, as there is only 1 line provided in the comment.

I am using the fllowing code,

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
AssetFileDescriptor fd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];
fis.read(b);
```

Please give your kind sugestions. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by myself, and I'm posting the answer in case of somebody get the similar problem and stuck for the solution. So the code before `byte[] b = new byte[(int)fd.getDeclaredLength()];` is same. Change this line to `byte[] buf = readBytes(fis);` and the method `readBytes(FileInputStream fis)` is below.

```
public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    // and then we can return your byte array.
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Hope this help. Cheers