# Android geocoder location returns different address for same location points

Tags: android, android-location, google-geocoder

I am using android geocoder to determine the address for latitude , longitude points .
but as i observed that , it is returning different address for same location points.
is that the way geocoder works ?? if so is there any workaround .

Thanks.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906380/problems-with-android-location-geocoder

Comment: It is because of the accuracy in meters. and the source of the location. that could be GPS, wifi, cellular.

Comment: but even though i am standing at the same position , it gives me different address , it is the network i am using

Comment: I think if you look at the lat/long it too is different for each test. If you are using a snapshot of the lat/long see if have access to an average lat/long that will smooth out the errors. (just guessing from background using old school GPS.)