# how to correctly show position

Tags: android, dialog, gps

I simple want to show a dialog with the following information:

- actual postal code
- actual street name
- actual precision

I don't want to handle location changes right now, just show these information (as text) in an dialog.

But the problem is, that the `addresses` variable always have zero size. I tried it in two different ways:

```
 AppLocationService appLocationService = new AppLocationService ( HintergrundService.this );
    Location location = appLocationService.getLocation ( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

    if (location == null) {
        Address adresse = new Address(null);
    }
    Geocoder gc =new Geocoder(getApplicationContext ());
    Address address=null;
    List<Address> addresses= null;
    try {
        addresses = gc.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        address=addresses.get(0);
        Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (), "" + addresses.get(0).getFeatureName () + "|" + addresses.get ( 0 ).getPostalCode (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    } else if(addresses.size () <= 0){
        Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (), "Liste leer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
    }
```

And with this:

```
AppLocationService appLocationService = new AppLocationService ( HintergrundService.this );
    // Location location = appLocationService.getLocation ( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );

    Location location = getLocation ();

    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;

    if ( location != null ) {
        Log.d ( "location", "location " + location + "|" + latitude  );
        latitude = location.getLatitude ();
        longitude = location.getLongitude ();
    }


    final double finalLatitude = latitude;
    final double finalLongitude = longitude;
    final String[] result = { null };

    //Thread thread = new Thread() {
    // @Override
    // public void run() {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder ( getApplicationContext (), Locale.getDefault () );


    try {
        List< Address > addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation (location.getLatitude (), location.getLongitude (), 1 );

        Log.d("location1", "location1 " + addressList + "|" + addressList.size () + "|" + geocoder);
        if ( addressList != null && addressList.size () > 0 ) {
            Address address = addressList.get ( 0 );
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex () ; i++ ) {
                sb.append ( address.getAddressLine ( i ) ).append ( "\n" );
            }
            sb.append ( address.getLocality () ).append ( "\n" );
            sb.append ( address.getPostalCode () ).append ( "\n" );
            sb.append ( address.getCountryName () );
            result[ 0 ] = sb.toString ();
            Log.d("stringbuilder", "stringbuilder " + sb + "|" + address.getLocality () + "|" + address.getPostalCode () + "|" + address.getCountryName ());
        }
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        Log.d ( "geocoder", "geocoder", e );
    }

    Toast.makeText ( HintergrundService.this, "result: " + result[ 0 ], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
```

In both ways the `addresses` or the `adressList` variable have got zero size.

**Solved:** 
The problem was, that the `Geocoder` Object isn't available with an android emulator. See this post: [Does the geocoder work on emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061175/does-the-geocoder-work-on-emulators)

There is a way to test this with: `Geocoder.isPresent()`. This return `false` with the emulator.

When `Geocoder.isPresent()` return `false` then I use the google api and get the location via `JSON`:

```
 if (location != null) {
        final boolean status = Geocoder.isPresent ();

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LocationAddress locationAddress = new LocationAddress();

        if(status) {
            locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation ( latitude, longitude, getApplicationContext (), handler = new Handler ( Looper.getMainLooper () ) {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage ( Message message ) {
                    String locationAddress;
                    switch ( message.what ) {
                        case 1:
                            Bundle bundle = message.getData ();
                            locationAddress = bundle.getString ( "address" );
                            break;
                        default:
                            locationAddress = null;
                    }
                    Log.d ( "locationAdress", "locationAdress " + locationAddress );
                }
            } );
        } else {

            final Dialog zeige_gps_daten = new Dialog ( getApplicationContext () );

            String currentLocation = LocationAddress.getCurrentLocationViaJSON ( latitude, longitude);
            Log.d("currentLocation1", "currentLocation1 " + currentLocation);

            String get_location = LocationAddress.get_location ();
            String get_street_adress = LocationAddress.get_street_adress ();
            String get_postal = LocationAddress.get_postal ();
            String get_ortsteil = LocationAddress.get_Ortsteil ();
            String get_land = LocationAddress.get_land ();

            zeige_gps_daten.getWindow ().setType ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT );

            zeige_gps_daten.setContentView ( R.layout.gps_daten_layout );


            TextView straße = (TextView)zeige_gps_daten.findViewById ( R.id.straße_text );
            TextView postleitzahl = (TextView)zeige_gps_daten.findViewById ( R.id.postleitzahl_text );
            TextView ortsteil = (TextView)zeige_gps_daten.findViewById ( R.id.ortsteil_text );
            TextView land = (TextView)zeige_gps_daten.findViewById ( R.id.land_text );

            zeige_gps_daten.setTitle ( "aktuelle Position" );

            straße.setText ( "Straße: " + get_street_adress );       // passt
            postleitzahl.setText ( "Postleitzahl: " + get_postal );
            ortsteil.setText ( "Ort: " + get_ortsteil );
            land.setText ( "Land: " + get_land  );

            zeige_gps_daten.show ();
        }


    }
```

This call the `getCurrentLocationViaJSON()` method:

```
public static String getCurrentLocationViaJSON(double lat, double lng) {

    JSONObject jsonObj = getLocationInfo ( lat, lng );
    Log.i ( "JSON string =>", jsonObj.toString () );

    currentLocation = "testing";
     street_address = null;
     postal_code = null;
    ortsteil = null;
    land = null;

    try {
        String status = jsonObj.getString("status").toString();
        Log.i("status", status);

        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
            JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
            int i = 0;
            Log.i("i", i+ "," + results.length() ); //TODO delete this
            do{

                JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray typesArray = r.getJSONArray("types");
                String types = typesArray.getString(0);

                if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("street_address")){
                    street_address = r.getString("formatted_address").split(",")[0];
                    Log.i("street_address", street_address);
                }else if(types.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code")){
                   // postal_code = r.getString("formatted_address");
                    postal_code = r.getString("formatted_address").split ( " " )[0];
                    ortsteil = r.getString("formatted_address").split ( " " )[1];
                    land = r.getString("formatted_address").split ( " " )[2];

                    Log.i("postal_code", postal_code + "|" + ortsteil + "|" + land);
                }

                if(street_address!=null && postal_code!=null){
                    currentLocation = street_address + "," + postal_code;
                    Log.i("Current Location =>", currentLocation); //Delete this
                    i = results.length();
                }

                i++;
            }while(i<results.length());

            Log.i("JSON Geo Locatoin =>", currentLocation);
            return currentLocation;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("testing","Failed to load JSON");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

as you can see I split the String with this (because the original string of `postal_code = r.getString("formatted_address");` return a String in this format: ('street name' 'postal code' 'location', 'country'):

```
postal_code = r.getString("formatted_address").split ( " " )[0];
ortsteil = r.getString("formatted_address").split ( " " )[1];
land = r.getString("formatted_address").split ( " " )[2];
```

The `getCurrentLocationViaJSON()` method call the `getLocationInfo` method:

```
public static JSONObject getLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat+","+lng +"&sensor=true");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

Important are these lines (because `StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork`will thrown):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Do you have a value location.getLatutude() and location.getLongitude()?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried this out: I have values for these: 47.783298|9.6167

Comment: I think there are some places that the geocoder cannot detect. I also experienced this issue. What I did here is when the address size is 0 i will do an api request on https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I know now why the problem occured: I tested my application in an emulator. Geocoder.isPresent() returns false. Have you got a link for me how to do an api request?

Comment: I found some ressources to get the location via JSON. Everythings works. Thanks a lot for helping