# Google map Geocoder And MoveToRegion not working

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, google-geocoder

I' have a very strange issue with Xamarin.Forms.Maps.
I'm trying to implement a page with a map that get current location and move to region at page start.

All is working fine in IOS, but in Android, Geocoder & MoveToRegion are not working at all. Only the map is displayed.

I retrieve the location correctly (Long & Lat ) in the emulators & device.
**MoveToRegion** do nothing & **GetAddressesForPositionAsync** retrive nothing.

Here the information in my manifest :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="mykey" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Here the code :

```
map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(coordinates.Lat.Value, coordinates.Lng.Value), Distance.FromMiles(1))
            );

        var possibleAddresses = await locator.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);
```

I tried in Genymotion, Emulator from AVD.
I'm not able to test in real device ( The deployment fail in my tablet )

**Edit :**

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
```

Was correctly set but still not working.

I force geocoder usage and it thrown this error :

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Java.IO.IOException: grpc failed
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <6cd960837cc24c26bab2a0a29b597627>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <6cd960837cc24c26bab2a0a29b597627>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Locations.Geocoder.GetFromLocationName (System.String locationName, System.Int32 maxResults) [0x0003c] in <d278c06ad5684d6882c743a94a93ebc2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Locations.Geocoder+<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<GetFromLocationNameAsync>b__0 () [0x00000] in <d278c06ad5684d6882c743a94a93ebc2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.GeocoderBackend+<GetPositionsForAddressAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0006b] in <39c694c022be4f7b8a39897d372b2d00>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Picaplant.Views.GeolocationPage+<HandleAdressCompleted>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00047] in /Users/OrcusZ/Documents/AutoEntrepreneur/Picaplant/Source/Picaplant/Views/GeolocationPage.xaml.cs:158 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <d278c06ad5684d6882c743a94a93ebc2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <d278c06ad5684d6882c743a94a93ebc2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <d278c06ad5684d6882c743a94a93ebc2>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:6621ff63-14b8-4291-a222-45bff630bddc (intptr,intptr)
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.io.IOException: grpc failed
[MonoDroid]     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
[MonoDroid]
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Same error with *Xamarin Form Working with maps sample*

Any idea ?

Comment: `mykey` means you have add the key? And I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yes, I hide the true key with the work mykey to do not display it. The map display correctly, i'm able to interact with it.

Comment: Try to deploy on a real deice, if there is any problem, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok, I will try on a tablet.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Same issue in the tablet

Comment: Have you checked with breakpoints to see if any error happens and they just pass something?

Comment: Do you have location tracking enabled on the device that you test with?

Comment: no errors are throwns, juste nothing happens. I can have a look to the output console.

Comment: Both `Geocoder` and `MoveToRegion` worked just fine in a **Samsung Android** device. This is for a portable cross-platform app.

Comment: That possible that my Google map API is bad configurer ? Should I need Google Places for geocoder ?

Comment: I did remove an IP restriction I had in my Maps API key, setting it to none. I do have Maps Geocoding and Google Places APIs, but the dashboard shows no traffic for these, so it doesn't seem they are being used. Neither do I have any related assembly in my project.

Comment: One piece of boilerplate code I had to "manually" add to my **App.Android** project, in the `OnCreate` method for `MainActivity.cs` : `global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);`.

Comment: `MoveToRegion` also works in my **KitKat 4.4 API Level 19** emulator. [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/02/02/installing-google-play-gapps-visual-studio-android-emulators/) is helpful setting it up.

Comment: `Geocoder` returns an empty address list in the same emulator though. Look at [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061175/does-the-geocoder-work-on-emulators).

Comment: I will have a look to this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working cross-platform sample app. It runs in a **KitKat 4.4 API Level 19** emulator and also in a **Samsung Android** device.
We also present a custom `Geocoder` implementation using HTTP requests given that the standard one works fine for an actual Android device but returns an empty response for the emulator.

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps.dll"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App20"
             x:Class="App20.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Maps:Map x:Name="map1" Grid.Row="0"></Maps:Map>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AddressList}" Grid.Row="1" />
            <Button Text="Move To Region" Grid.Row="2" Clicked="Button_Clicked_Move"></Button>
            <Button Text="Get Address" Grid.Row="3" Clicked="Button_Clicked_Address"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**CS:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MyViewModel vm;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        map1.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            new Position(vm.Lat, vm.Lon), Distance.FromMiles(vm.Distance)));
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked_Address(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder();

        var list = await gc.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(new Position(vm.Lat, vm.Lon));

        if (list.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in list)
                vm.AddressList.Add(s);
        }
        else
        {
            MyGeocoder mgc = new MyGeocoder();

            var mylist = await mgc.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(vm.Lat, vm.Lon, vm.Key);

            foreach (string s in mylist)
                vm.AddressList.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> AddressList { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Lat = 40.706501;
        Lon = -74.011340;
        Distance = 0.5;
        Key = "YOUR_API_KEY";
        AddressList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

**Custom Geocoder:**

```
public class MyGeocoder
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAddressesForPositionAsync(double lat, double lon, string key)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var request = string.Format(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={0},{1}&key={2}", lat, lon, key);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync(request);

        var result = JObject.Parse(json)["results"];

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (JToken jt in result)
            list.Add((string)jt["formatted_address"]);

        return list.AsEnumerable<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I find that the issue comes from my map Custom Renderer to implement a Tap event. Now I can find a solution ^^

Comment: If by _not working_ you mean an _empty response_, that's more likely due to the fact that Google Play for emulators don't come with the necessary backing service, as pointed out in the articles linked before. If you're still getting an exception though, you should post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and for sure you would get help much faster with more people willing to help.

Comment: If i put a breakpoint, it never go to next step. You can have a look to this fresh post about my geocode error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894719/xamarin-forms-geocode-android

Comment: Does it work without wrapping it in a `Task`? You need to take incremental troubleshooting steps to isolate the problem.

Comment: Same thing without the Task. Your implementation will work but I will have a request limitation :/

Comment: I'm not even sure you would benefit from spawning a new `Task` here... Take a look at [THIS ARTICLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx#Threads), in particular, **IO-bound** and **CPU-bound** work. Here's an excerpt of interest from the article: _You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available._ `Geocoder` methods are clearly **IO-Bound**, given that it will make HTTP calls to the corresponding google APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I will have a look and try to find why is not working. Thanks a lot for your time