# Xamarin Forms Geocode Android

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, geocoding

I Have two pieces of code, one to get adresses from a position & one to get position from adress.

**GetAddressesForPosition**

```
 var geoCoder = new Geocoder();

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var firstAdress = possibleAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
                    GeolocationAdressEntry.Text = firstAdress;
                    //GeolocationAdressEntry.Text = $@"{firstAdresse.} {firstAdresse.PostalCode} {firstAdresse.Locality}";
                });

            });
```

For this code, I not have any exception and the code never goes after

```
var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);
```

**GetPositionsForAddress**

```
var elem = (Entry)sender;
            var geoCoder = new Geocoder();

            IEnumerable<Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position> loc;

            try
            {
                loc = await geoCoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(elem.Text);

                var firstLoc = loc.FirstOrDefault();
                var adress = elem.Text;

                CreateNewPin(firstLoc, adress);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

For this one it thrown an error : "grpc failed". If needed I can post the complete error.

This is boring because it works perfectly in IOS.

I tried on emulators ( Genymotion & adb ) with different versions and also in a true device. Same issue.

Comment: I only get this on emulators, it's a known limitation with Android emulators. As for the device, my code works on all the test devices I have, from Android 4.4 -> Android 7.1.   Are you sure you've set up your Google API key correctly for your Android project?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to upload this thread. You are totally right, this is an emulator issue the code work perfeclty in device ( Seems that 4.4 need sometime a reboot to work )

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the emulator. Code work in a true device.