# Problems with LocationManager Android 4.4.1

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager, android-location

I want to get the current location of the user in my app. Everytime i use the `LocationManager` get this error:

> The method requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, int, MainActivity).

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              //I get error in this line            
          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double latitude = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        double longitude = (double) (location.getLongitude());
        Log.i("Geo_Location", "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude);
    }

}
```

Also LocationListener implementations throws me an error, and must be implemented like this `android.location.LocationListener`

Any help I will really appreciate.

PD: I'm using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Its a long time since I have worked with any android stuff but built a location app last year and this is how I implemented the location listener and it all worked fine.

[problems with android.location.geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906380/problems-with-android-location-geocoder)

NOTE: Not all code at the link is relative to your problem but the structure may help