# apache commons IOUtils.toByteArray not compiling for android

Tags: android, uri, arrays, inputstream, apache-commons

I want to use the method

```
byte[] IOUtils.toByteArray(Uri uri)
```

from `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`. My Uri is a typical android uri of type `android.net.Uri`. Does anyone know how I may fix this? An intermediary might be getting the input stream from the uri. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Sorry - why does it have to be apache-commons IOUtils? You can do this with an InputStream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436385/android-getting-from-a-uri-to-an-inputstream-to-a-byte-array

Comment: I didn't want to roll out my own method and then spend too much time hunting down possible bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache commons works fine with the following:

```
context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] attachmentBites = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Comment: Your question was how to use IOUtils.toByteArray with android.net.Uri . You don't need an InputStream. I think my answer is accurate and up to the question, please be scrupulous and accept/ upvote an answer

Comment: Thanks for the input. Given this answer uses much fewer lines, I accept it. I +1 your response. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The method uses a `java.net.URI` (ref: [IOUtils javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html)), not an `android.net.Uri`.

So the example use would be something like:

```
android.net.URI auri = new android.net.URI(whatever);
java.net.URI juri = new java.net.URI(auri.toString());
try {
    byte[] output = IOUtils.toByteArray(juri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(presuming you have already imported and included in your build path the `org.apache.commons.io` library)