# File not found in external sd

Tags: android, inputstream, android-external-storage

I am trying to read an audio file that I have previously saved on my external storage but it seems that I cannot find it with the methods that I am using.

This is what I use in order to save the file in the external sdcard;

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ejemplo.3gpp";
```

And this is what I use in order to get back the byteArray of the audio file recorded:

```
InputStream is =this.openFileInput("/sdcard/ejemplo.3gpp"); 
bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

For some reason, it seems that when I call openFileInput is not able to find the file, but with "Root browser" I have checked that actually the file is placed in "/sdcard/ejemplo.3gpp" so I dont know what is going on .... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/sdcard/ is not default. It can be changed by OEM and in some devices it is sdcard0 So use the Environment class as you use it to save the file.

```
File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ejemplo.3gpp");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Comment: Now it seems that it finds the file, but for any reason the array that I got in return in just an array of 0`s ... but I can hear back the sound recorded and everything seems to be ok ... any idea about what is going on?

Comment: Both permissions for write and read external storage are added

Comment: Don't know why it is giving only zero. You can try some other methods to convert `inputstream` to `byte array`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2436385/909317