# How to not pulse DTR & RTS lines when opening serial port w RXTX

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, rxtx

We have a device that is sensitive to the RS232 DTR and RTS lines and are using the RXTX API to connect to a linux serial port however opening the connection causes pulses on these lines and is resetting our device. Is there a way to configure the connection to not pulse the lines when the connection is open?

This is the approach we currently use:

```
    // Set up the serial port
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(serialPortID);
    if (portId.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
        TRACE.severe("Port " + portId.getName() + " (port ID = " + serialPortID
                + ") is already in use by owner: " + portId.getCurrentOwner());
        throw new PortInUseException();
    }
    CommPort commPort = portId.open(this.getClass().getName(), responseTimeout);
    if (!(commPort instanceof SerialPort)) {
        TRACE.severe("Error: Only serial ports are supported.");
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: Only serial ports are supported.");
    }
    SerialPort serialPort = commPort;

    try {
        serialPort.setDTR(false);
        serialPort.setRTS(false);
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(baudRate, dataBits, stopBits, parity);
        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
        // set the port blocking mode recommended from stack overflow.
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219450/rxtx-serial-connection-issue-with-blocking-read
        serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(responseTimeout);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
        ApplicationManager.logStackTrace(e);
    }
```

If this is not supported by RXTX are alternative java libraries able to suppress these pulses? Does anyone know if these pulses are expected behavior per the RS232 specification?

Comment: Are you using HW flow-control? Have you tried to disable HW flow-control before you start your program using `stty -F /dev/ttyXXX -crtscts -cdtrdsr +clocal` from the shell? What about using a serial cable that does not connect those signals (aka a 3-wire cable)?

Comment: We can't remove those wires bc we use them to switch the board into a programming mode and back. Will look into disabling hw flow control which we do not intend to use.

Comment: This is a well-known issue deeply rooted in hardware, operating system and USB protocol. The application software cannot do anything about it. That's why all ESP32 boards use a special *auto reset circuit* with two transistors. You don't happen to be working with an ESP32, do you?

Comment: [jSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm) is a better maintained and more powerful alternative to RXTX. They are faced with the same challenges and discuss some workarounds. See [Issue #523](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/issues/523).

Comment: [nrjavaserial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) is a fork of jrxtx that is also still maintained. Maybe this is an alternative for you. But I am not sure if this library has the same issues